# Java 6 Map.get() Type Safety Unexpected Behavior(?)

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)

According to the javadocs (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for the Map interface, the definition of get is

> V get(Object key) 
>             Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null
>   if this map contains no mapping for
>   the key.

Code Example:

```
Map<InstrumentInfo, Double> moo = new HashMap<InstrumentInfo,Double>();
moo.get(new Integer(5));
```

I would expect that the above code will throw an exception or at least give a warning.

I would expect that with generics and type safety, the get method would take in a parameter of type .  What is the reason for taking in type Object and not ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discussed  in this question [What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic), as well...

Answer (score 1):

The definition of Map.get is **Y get(Object key)** for a **Map< X,Y >** and the Map.get will return  (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k) , which I'd expect to return null, unless your InstrumentInfo have overloaded .equals to be able to compare to Integers.

Why **Y get(Object key)** isn't **Y get(X key)** I don't know though, but I'm guessing it has to do with backwards compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

It will just return null, since the map can never include the key.

This is the same reason why you can `remove()` a `Integer` from an `ArrayList<String>` - it worked before generics so it was kept that way for not breaking old code.