# Why does this code with generics compile?

Tags: java, generics

This seems like a stupid question, but I'm tripping over it at the moment.  Why does this compile?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
        public static void main (String[] argv) throws Exception {
                Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                map.get(new ArrayList<String>());
        }
}
```

Shouldn't it be illegal to call get with something that's not compatible with "String"?

Comment: Run FindBugs and it will complain about the bad object type used in get().

Comment: As the asker, I'm voting to close as a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045721/java-6-map-get-type-safety-unexpected-behavior/1045758#1045758)
Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)

Comment: You should give context when providing links

Comment: Thanks for the links.  It looks like the reason is basically that they wanted backwards compatibility even at the cost of making the API more painful.  Sadly, this makes converting to generics harder in a lot of cases, rather than easier.

Comment: Duly noted... i wont edit since this is question is now voted as closed

Answer (score 3):

From the Javadocs for [Map](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
V get(Object key)
```

> Returns the value to which the
>   specified key is mapped, or null if
>   this map contains no mapping for the
>   key.

get is simply a method which takes in ANY object, and will (if it exists) return an object that was mapped to it. So passing it a non-string is legal, however, since all the keys have to be strings, you'll always get null if you pass in a non-string.

Comment: I think you mean "always" get null. :)

Comment: You're quoting from the 1.4.2 docs, while to OP uses 1.5 syntax.

Comment: "you'll always get null if you pass in a non-string" Not if the object you pass in has a .equals() method that returns true for strings.

Comment: @newacct - Excellent point, and this is a big part of the reason why they defined it the way they did.  It's still more annoying than useful, though, imo.

Answer (score 1):

The [`get()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) method for `Map` just takes an `Object`, not the generic type `K`.

The code will compile, but will never get anything out of the Map.

Answer (score 1):

`Map.get` takes an `Object`, not a generic type, cf. the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

> `get(Object key)`: Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.

The important thing is that it returns a generic type, so you do not have to cast the return value.