# Java Map<K,V> : Why get(object) not get(K)?

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Generics: Why Does Map.get() Ignore Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455138/java-generics-why-does-map-get-ignore-type)

Could someone please explain why with Map defines

```
V put(K key,V value);
V get(Object key);
```

Why is `get` not defined as:

```
V get(K key)
```

Similarly, why are these methods typed to `Object`, and not `K` and `V` respectively?

```
boolean containsKey(Object key); // Why not K?
boolean containsValue(Object value); // Why not V?
```

Is this a backwards compatibility thing (pre 1.5)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455138/java-generics-why-does-map-get-ignore-type

Comment: Agree - thanks.  Will flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good explanations can be found in the answers of

[What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)

and

[Java Generics: Why Does Map.get() Ignore Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455138/java-generics-why-does-map-get-ignore-type)

Answer (score 0):

Templates goal is to enforce control at compilation time (you cannot put a Cat in a Dog List), and to simplify the programmer's code, by suppressing the explicit casts.

In theses methods, there is no need of templates. if you compare (with "equals" a cat and a dog), it has no incidence. More, two objets of differents classes can be "equals" ! A too restrictive method signature would limit the use of the Map.

Note : the template informations are only verified at compilation, but are lost after. At runtime, by reflexion, you can put a Cat in a Dog list...