# Why Map.containsKey() takes an Object parameter instead of a speciallized type?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)
>   [Java Generics: Why Does Map.get() Ignore Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455138/java-generics-why-does-map-get-ignore-type)

Java [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) interface is declared like this:

```
Interface Map<K,V>
```

It has such a method:

```
boolean containsKey(Object key)
```

Why not 
 `boolean containsKey(K key)`?

On the contrary, the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) interface has add method that takes parameter of generic type instead of `Object`:

```
boolean add(E e).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same reason why you can't add anything to a `List<? extends E>` because the compiler can't guarantee the type safety (and type erasure makes a runtime check impossible).

This means that when you get a `Map<? extends K,V>` you wouldn't be able to call `contains(K)` on it. however `contains` is general enough that passing random `Object`s to it won't damage the interface (but makes some errors harder to pick up).

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces are consistent in how they operate, though I can't give the initial reasons.

```
Interface Map<K,V>
    boolean containsKey(Object key)
    V put(K key, V value)

Interface List<E>
    boolean contains(Object o)
    boolean add(E e)
```

In both cases, the contains methods take Objects, and the insert operations take generic types.