# Why we do not have Map.get(K key)

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)
>   [Java Generics: Why Does Map.get() Ignore Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455138/java-generics-why-does-map-get-ignore-type)

Is there any reason why we do not have

```
Map.get(K key)
```

But we have

```
Map.get(Object key)
```

Isn't the generic version will be better, so that we can perform compile time checking?

Comment: Has been asked before: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455138/java-generics-why-does-map-get-ignore-type>