# Why does Java's Hashtable's get method take an Object as a parameter?

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)

From the JDK Documentation, the put method:

```
  public V put(K key, V value)
```

but, the get method:

```
  public V get(Object key)
```

Any ideas?

Note: In some code I inherited, there is a bug, where someone used a String as a parameter to the get method of a Hashtable with an Integer key.

Comment: I feel your pain, I've been bit by this one before. Lost couple a hours tracking it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This allows any `Object` which is equivalent to a given key to get the value.

For example, you may have two classes that override the `equals` method to return true in case of being compared to each-other. Since the objects are equivalent, they should both be able to get the value.

This is the same reason the equals method has an `Object` parameter.

Comment: But why doesn't it take A K as a parameter? That way at least the compiler can tell me I've made a mistake.

Comment: Because if it took only objects of type K, then you wouldn't be able to get the value using an object of a different type, even though that object is equivalent to the one of type K.

Comment: Wouldn't this reasoning also apply to put?

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method will take any `Object` as the key simply because any object is able to be stored in a `HashMap` (as all objects are a subclass of type `Object`).

It just checks the .equals method for that `Object` to return the match in the `HashMap`.

Comment: But why doesn't it take a K as a parameter?

Comment: This doesn't explain why they wouldn't use the generics type provided when creating the collection.