# Why does Seq.contains accept type Any rather than the type parameter A?

Tags: scala

For example:

```
scala> val l:List[String] = List("one", "two")
l: List[String] = List(one, two)

scala> l.contains(1) //wish this didn't compile
res11: Boolean = false
```

[The various explanations of why things were done this way in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic) don't seem to apply as much here, as Map and Set do implement the type-safe version of `contains` and friends.  Is there any way to do a type-safe `contains` on a Seq short of cloning it into a Set?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that `Seq` is covariant in its type parameter.  This makes a lot of sense for the majority of its functionality.  As an immutable container, it really *should* be covariant.  Unfortunately, this does get in the way when they have to define a method which takes some of the parameterized type.  Consider the following example:

```
trait Seq[+A] {
  def apply(i: Int): A       // perfectly valid

  def contains(v: A): Boolean   // does not compile!
}
```

The problem is that functions are always contravariant in their parameter types and covariant in their return types.  Thus, the `apply` method can return a value of type `A` because `A` is covariant along with the return type for `apply`.  However, `contains` *cannot* take a value of type `A` because its parameter must be contravariant.

This problem can be solved in different ways.  One option is to simply make `A` an invariant type parameter.  This allows it to be used in both covariant and contravariant contexts.  However, this design would mean that `Seq[String]` would *not* be a subtype of `Seq[Any]`.  Another option (and the one most often used) is to employ a local type parameter which is bounded below by the covariant type.  For example:

```
trait Seq[+A] {
  def +[B >: A](v: B): Seq[B]
}
```

This trick retains the `Seq[String] <: Seq[Any]` property as well as provides some very intuitive results when writing code which uses heterogeneous containers.  For example:

```
val s: Seq[String] = ...
s + 1      // will be of type Seq[Any]
```

The results of the `+` function in this example is a value of type `Seq[Any]`, because `Any` is the least upper-bound (LUB) for the types `String` and `Int` (in other words, the least-common supertype).  If you think about it, this is exactly the behavior we would expect.  If you create a sequence with both `String` and `Int` components, then its type *should* be `Seq[Any]`.

Unfortunately, this trick, while applicable to methods like `contains`, produces some surprising results:

```
trait Seq[+A] {
  def contains[B >: A](v: B): Boolean    // compiles just fine
}

val s: Seq[String] = ...
s contains 1        // compiles!
```

The problem here is that we are calling the `contains` method passing a value of type `Int`.  Scala sees this and tries to infer a type for `B` which is a supertype of both `Int` and `A`, which in this case is instantiated as `String`.  The LUB for these two types is `Any` (as shown earlier), and so the local type instantiation for `contains` will be `Any => Boolean`.  Thus, the `contains` method *appears* to not be type safe.

This result isn't an issue for `Map` or `Set` because neither of them are covariant in their parameter types:

```
trait Map[K, +V] {
  def contains(key: K): Boolean    // compiles
}

trait Set[A] {
  def contains(v: A): Boolean      // also compiles
}
```

So, long story short, the `contains` method on covariant container types cannot be restricted to only take values of the component type because of the way that functions types work (contravariant in their parameter types).  This isn't really a limitation of Scala or bad implementation, it's a mathematical fact.

The consolation prize is that this really isn't an issue in practice.  And, as the other answers have mentioned, you can always define your own implicit conversion which adds a "type-safe" `contains`-like method if you *really* need the extra check.

Comment: It's a pity that there isn't a mechanism to instruct the compiler about those parameters that are only formally there to satisfy type requirements and can be narrowed in a specific context.  It is provably true that List[B] can only contain B, but it is also true that List[B] might be re-interpreted as List[A] where B<:A and then could be asked (fruitlessly) about A.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening here.  `Seq[String]` is being re-interpreted as `Seq[Any]`, and since `Int <: Any`, we can then ask (fruitlessly) about `Int`.

Comment: I'd love to see the mathematics due to which this becomes a mathematical fact (beyond the exponent functor being contravariant).

Comment: Re "consolation prize is that this really isn't an issue in practice": one issue is that a user might confuse `contains` and `exists`. You don't get a compiler error when you do `List(1,2).contains((x: Int) => x == 2)`, you just get `false`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why things were designed this way--possibly to mirror something in Java.

Anyway, it's more efficient to use the pimp-my-library pattern than to clone into a set:

```
class SeqWithHas[T](s: Seq[T]) {
  def has(t: T) = s.contains(t)
}
implicit def seq2seqwithhas[T](s: Seq[T]) = new SeqWithHas(s)

scala> List("3","5") has 1
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: java.lang.String
       List("3","5") has 1
                         ^

scala> List("3","5") has "1"
res1: Boolean = false
```

(You'll probably want to put this stuff and other handy such things into a single object and then import MyHandyObject._ in most of your source files.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to forgo infix in favor of a regular method call, defining and importing the following has(...) method will avoid creating an instance every time you need the type-safe "has" test (worthwhile in inner loops, e.g.):

```
def has[T](s: Set[T], t: T) = s.contains(t)
```

Naturally, Set[T] can be relaxed to the least specific type that has a contains method.

Comment: This comment field is too small to post the code, but the optimizations are pretty good at allowing the infix method to cause only a little slowdown:

implicit vs. method (2M tests on length 3 list):
1247 vs 1141;
1215 vs 1076;
1184 vs 1091;
1181 vs 1087;
1180 vs 1085;
1183 vs 1095;
1200 vs 1103;
1203 vs 1093;
1183 vs 1088;
1188 vs 1087.

Not too bad--about 10% overhead for the implicit object creation.

Answer (score 0):

By supplying an evidence for type equality,

```
def contains[A,B](xs: List[A], x: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B) = xs.contains(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the second question about a type-safe `contains`, if you're using `cats`, `contains_` is available on [UnorderedFoldables](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.typelevel/cats-docs_2.13/2.9.0/cats/UnorderedFoldable.html#contains_%5BA%5D(fa:F%5BA%5D,v:A)(implicitev:cats.Eq%5BA%5D):Boolean):

```scala
import cats.syntax.unorderedFoldable._

val mySeq = Seq(1, 2, 3)

mySeq.contains_(1)  // fine

mySeq.contains_("1")  // compile error
```