# Why is a Set a function?

Tags: scala, math

In Scala a `Set` is a function:

```
trait Set[A] extends (A => Boolean)
```

This make it impossible to have a covariant immutable `Set` because type `A` occurs in contravariant position. In contrast `Seq` is not defined as a function. There is already some content about the question why Sets and Seqs are designed this way:

- [Why is Scala's immutable Set not covariant in its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type)
- [Scala: Why does Seq.contains take an Any argument, instead of an argument of the sequence type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678998/scala-why-does-seq-contains-take-an-any-argument-instead-of-an-argument-of-the)
- [Why does Seq.contains accept type Any rather than the type parameter A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078246/why-does-seq-contains-accept-type-any-rather-than-the-type-parameter-a)

One answer says that the reason for this is the mathematical background. But this answer wasn't explained a little more. So, what are the concrete advantages to define a `Set` as a function or what would be the disadvantages if it is implemented differently?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6183115/358642) to the first question you linked says a lot more than the other ones.

Comment: By the way, why if I call the function `foo` in first linked question as foo(Set("asd")), it compiles?

Comment: I think that is because the `apply` method in [`SetFactory`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/generic/SetFactory.scala) is flexible enough to produce sets of different element type that just the arguments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The set of type `Set[A]` has to have a method that tests if an element of type `A` is in the set. This method (`apply`) has to have a parameter of type `A` representing that element, and that parameter is in the contravariant position. This means that sets cannot be covariant in their type parameter `A`. So - it's not the extending of the function interface that makes it impossible to have covariant immutable sets, it's the existence of the contravariant `apply` method.

And for reasons of convenience, it makes sense to extend the `Function1` interface to be able to pass sets around and treat them as functions.

By contrast, sequence abstraction doesn't have a method that tests if an element is in the sequence, it only has the indexing method - `apply` takes an integer index, and returns the element at that index. Sequences are also defined as functions, but functions of type `Int => A` (which are covariant in `A`), not `A => Boolean`, as sets.

If you want to know more about how type safety would be broken if sets were defined as covariant in their type parameter `A`, see this example in which the set implementation does some writing to private members for reasons of caching the lookups (below `@uV` is the annotation which disables variance checking and `expensiveLookup` is meant to simulate a call to a computationally expensive check if an element is in the set):

```
import annotation.unchecked.{uncheckedVariance => uV}

trait Set[+A] {
  def apply(elem: A @uV): Boolean
}

class CachingSet[+A >: Null] extends Set[A] {
  private var lastLookup: (A @uV, Boolean) = (null, false)
  private def expensiveLookup(elem: A @uV) = (elem, true)
  def apply(elem: A @uV): Boolean = {
    if (elem != lastLookup._1) lastLookup = expensiveLookup(elem)
    lastLookup._2
  }
  def lastQueriedElement: A = lastLookup._1
}

object Main extends App {
  val css = new CachingSet[String]
  val csa: CachingSet[AnyRef] = css

  csa.apply(new AnyRef)
  val s: String = css.lastQueriedElement // you'll get a ClassCastException here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> In contrast Seq is not defined as a function.

Not true.

```
Seq[T] extends (Int) => T
```

Comment: That is surprising. I didn't notice that because the type parameter doesn't occur in contravariant position. Nice detail!

Comment: You're right, they extend partial function. I've corrected that.