# Why would one disable variance checking via @uV?

Tags: scala, annotations, type-safety

I just stumbled over the following definition of method `to` defined by [`TraversableLike`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala) (2.10.0):

```
override def to[Col[_]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, Col[A @uV]]): Col[A @uV] = {
  val b = cbf()
  b.sizeHint(this)
  b ++= thisCollection
  b.result
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8761517/491216), the `@uV` disabled variance checking. That sounds dangerous. Why would I want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer would be very similar to the one for this question: [When is @uncheckedVariance needed in Scala, and why is it used in GenericTraversableTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454281/when-is-uncheckedvariance-needed-in-scala-and-why-is-it-used-in-generictravers?rq=1)

Since builders (the implicit parameter `cbf`) exist for immutable (possibly covariant) and mutable (invariant) collections, the annotation is probably used here to make the `to` method work for both types of collections.