# Java Generics non-issue at compile time

Tags: java, generics

The code below compiles without error... for once I would have preferred it to fail :/

```
    Map <Character, Double> m = new HashMap <Character, Double>();
    m.get(new String());
```

Since the compiler knows that the key used in this map is of type Character, using a String key instead should be flagged as incorrect.

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not missing anything. All [`Map#get()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) calls simply take `Object`.

*Depending on the  implementation*, you might see a (runtime) `ClassCastException` when you pass a `String` to a `Map<Character, Double>#get()`.

---

[Here's why `Map#get()` isn't fully generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic).

Comment: Yep this is correct. String is an Object :) My IDE does throw a warning though

Comment: I think the purpose of this is to save legacy code. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Jeremy: see the SO question link I added.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an (optional) run-time exception (`ClassCastException`), if you try running this code.

Answer (score 1):

That the method get is not parametrized with generic parameter only the result is.

You can also do

```
m.get(1L); //m.get(Object o);
```

The parametrized method is put

```
m.put(new String(), 0.0); //Fail

//The method put(Character, Double) in the type Map<Character,Double> is not applicable for the arguments (String, double)

m.put(new Character('c'), 0.0); //Ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Map.get() takes an Object as its argument: [java.util.Map#get](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

`get` retrieves an object that the argument is `.equals()` to. It's possible for an object to be `.equals()` to an object of another class.