# Why does the key parameter in Map.get() is not generic?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)

Why for `Map<K,V>`, the `get()` is defined with an Object parameter:

```
V get(Object key)
```

and not a generic paramter:

```
V get(K key)
```

?

Comment: Good question but unfortunately, it is a duplicate. Will be closed.

Comment: This is answered --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic