# Why does JDK Map.get not support type inference on the return value

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-inference

As a follow-up question to [What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic), why does the JDK 6 and 7 `Map` interface not define the "get" method as a generic method so that the compiler can use type inference on the return value?

For example, if "get" were defined as:

```java
public <T extends V> T get(Object key)
```

then a caller could write:

```java
Map<String,Object> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("key", new Foo());
...
Foo f = m.get("key");   // type inference, implicit cast
```

In the snippet above, I could have defined m as `Map<String,Foo>`, but note that defining m as `Map<String,Object>` instead of `Map<String,Foo>` is useful in many situations, such as when m can contain values of any type, but the value type can still be inferred based on the key e.g. a simple cache or context object.

Comment: Isn't this just the same question?  Don't the answers to the question you linked to answer this one too?  If not, be more specific.  (My initial reaction was to simply vote-to-close as a duplicate ...)

Comment: No, it isn't the same at all. AFAICT, the question is explicit on the difference already, but to restate: I'm not asking about why key is of type Object -- that is answered in the referenced question. I'm asking about defining get as a generic method of type <T extends V>, which is clearly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it isn't (in general) safe to do this. A `Map<String, Object>` specifically declares that its values may be any type of `Object`, not just `Foo`, so in typical usage one should not be assigning its values to anything else. Doing so would be a programmer error usually, which the type system should (and does) help you avoid. If you want to do something like that, there's always casting, which makes your intent explicit.

Comment: That was my thinking as well. In addition to casting, another approach is to create a different interface for specific cases in which the programmer knows it **is** safe to do this. For example, a Cache or Context interface may use a generic method signature to avoid unnecessary casts, but since Map is a more general interface it makes sense to not make any unnecessary assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the compiler attempts to warn you about unsafe operations and an implicitly cast to what ever you need is considered unsafe.  You need to an explicit cast to show the developer "knows" what type to expect.

Java doesn't not support type inference on any return type.  It determines the return type of a method or expression and the assignment might do an implicit cast.

The only exception I have seen is MethodHandle.invokeExact() adding in Java 7 and has special handling by the JVM. Its a new feature and doesn't work in all cases. ;)