# Java. Override method

Tags: java, overriding

```
public class MyMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, Serializable>
{
    @Override
    public Serializable get(String key)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `@Override` annotation. That will fix the error.

Keep in mind that if you **actually** want to override some parent method, this is not what you want to do. Instead, look for possible typos, error or type mismatch in your `get` method.

In your case, you probably want:

```
@Override
public Object get(Object key)
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `get` is `public V get(Object key)`

So you need to change the parameter type to `Object` instead of `String`.

Answer (score 3):

The [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) you're trying to override has the following signature:

```
public Serializable get(Object key);
```

To override it, your method's argument therefore has to be of type `Object`, not `String`:

```
public class MyMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, Serializable>
{
    @Override
    public Serializable get(Object key)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why public V get(Object key) successfully overrides by 
    @Override
    public Serializable put(String key, Serializable value)
    {
    }
?

Comment: @user1034253: I am sorry but I don't understand the question.

Comment: public Serializable put(String key, Serializable value) - compiled,  public Serializable get(String key) as you say is need replace String by Object

Comment: @aix - OP's asking why `put` doesn't follow the same pattern. There's a popular post about this somewhere, we should just link it.

Comment: @user1034253 - See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic