# Why is guava's Cache.invalidate(Object key) method not generic?

Tags: java, caching, guava

From [the javadocs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/index.html):

```
public interface Cache<K,V> extends Function<K,V> {
    //...
    void invalidate(Object key);
    //...
}
```

Why is this not rendered as a generic method:

```
    void invalidate(K key);
```

Is there a technical reason, a historical reason, or some other reason?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the same reason that `Map.remove` takes an Object argument, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1283).

This reason is neither technical nor historical: it's just...an objectively sensible reason.

Comment: But why doesn't Cache have a `get(Object key)` method? :)

Comment: Because `Cache.get` and `LoadingCache.getUnchecked` can each cause entries to be _added_ to the cache, so it has to be of type `K` for the same reason that `Map.put` has to take a key of type `K`.  Admittedly, `getIfPresent` doesn't take an `Object` -- it forces its argument to be of type `K` -- and that was probably a judgement call.  (But `asMap().get` still takes an `Object`, and it's functionally equivalent to `getIfPresent`.)

Comment: Yea it does seem odd they conformed to the `Map` interface in some spots and not others though.

Comment: I'm not positive about the justification for `getIfPresent`, but I do know for a fact that these APIs were discussed and debated for _days_.

Comment: getIfPresent(K) may well have been an accident for all I remember.