# Generic type checking at compile time

Tags: java, generics

Let's see some `Set<E>`'s methods declarations.

```
public boolean add(E e);
public E get(int index);
```

And let's try to use this.

```
List<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
Integer i = list.get(0);              //Predictably, here we get a compile error.
list.contains(new Integer(3));        //But this line is allowed. Why?
```

Even in non-generic equivalent of this code (as I know, it'll simply transformed into it), we get compile errors in both lines.

```
List s = new ArrayList();
s.contains((Boolean)(new Integer(3)));
Integer i = (Boolean)s.get(3);
```

So why do not I get the error in the generic case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`contains` is not generified. Its signature remains:

```
boolean contains(Object o)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

here's some more: 
http://smallwig.blogspot.com/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html

Answer (score 3):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic).

basically the `contains()`, `remove()`, etc methods only care that the objects being compared against and removed are *equal*, not that they have the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this line:

```
s.contains((Boolean)(new Integer(3)));
```

has compile time error simply because you can't cast what's clearly an Integer instance to Boolean. It has nothing to do with List's generics.

Then, the `contains(Object o)` is not generically typed (inside java.util.Collection), that's why you don't get a compile time warning. This has to do with covariance and contra-variance.

Answer (score 1):

From List interface API:

```
E get(int index)
```

So it returns the object of generic type. While `contains` gets `Object` as a param:

```
boolean contains(Object o)
```

so it's all about methods signatures.
See more on [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)