# Generic in Google Multimap

Tags: java, guava

Do you have a reason why [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) is not completely generic?

```
containsEntry(Object key, Object value)
containsKey(Object key)
remove(Object key, Object value)
removeAll(Object key)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic) which is true also for Guava's Multimap. Also, you may want read [Kevin Bourrillion's blog entry](http://smallwig.blogspot.com/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html) (he's Guava lead dev) explaining the same issue (note that `add` uses generic type `E`):

> The real difference is that add() can cause "damage" to the
>   collection when called with the wrong type, and contains() and
>   remove() cannot.
>
> Uniformly, methods of the Java Collections Framework (and the Google
>   Collections Library too) never restrict the types of their parameters
>   except when it's necessary to prevent the collection from getting
>   broken.

Comment: Guava contributor here -- this is exactly correct, and explains why it would be _bad_ to make e.g. `containsKey` only accept a `K` and not an `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess its because they want a similar interface to the original [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface

Comment: Untrue... `Multimap` (note that it does not capitalize the m in the `map` part) does not implement the `Map` interface.