# Generic classes taking Object parameters - Java

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)

I have a question about the Generic java collections, specifically Map. I notice that the get, contains and similar methods that require a parameter (usually the key) take an Object as the parameter, while I would have expected them to take something of class K, e.g. rather than `get(Object key)` I would expect `get(K key)`. Can anyone explain the reason for this?

Comment: Think this will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic
The awesome power of the searchbar ;)

Comment: I had this question already, but I didn't take any time searching for an answer. Good question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic), it is because the object you pass to get does not have to be equal to the type of the key you are trying to retrieve.

The only condition is that their `equals` method return `true`.

**EDIT**: As Peter Lawrey pointed out, the `hashcode` should be the same.

Comment: hashCode should be the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is backward compatibility.

It was always possible to attempt to do the following, even if you "know" its not going to work

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("hello", "world");

Object o = map.get(1); // null
boolean b = map.contain(2); // false
boolean b2 = map.remove(3); // false
```

As a result these methods still need to be able to take any type even though the generics implies that it will always return `null` or `false`.

---

Also its possible to construct a TreeMap where the keys don't need to be the same type, equals true, have the same hashCode or even compareTo() == 0

```
Map map = new TreeMap(new Comparator() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return String.valueOf(o1).compareTo(o2.toString());
    }
});
map.put("1", "one");
map.put(2, "two");
map.put(3L, "three");
map.put('4', "four");

for(Object o: new Object[] { 1L, '2', 3, "4"}) {
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getSimpleName()+" "+o+" => "+map.get(o));
}
```

prints

```
Long 1 => one
Character 2 => two
Integer 3 => three
String 4 => four
```

Comment: well, see answer on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/857452/978502)

Comment: I wonder why the downvote. It seems reasonable, as Map existed before generics were introduced.