# Consistency of contains method on a HashSet and HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

Why does containsAll method on a HashSet does not remain consistent if remove is called on the Set whereas a containsValue method on a HashMap remains consistent after a value is removed 
After a value is removed from a HashSet containsAll returns false even if all values were present where as in case of HashMap the containsValue method returns correct value

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    HashSet<String> lookup=new HashSet<String>();
    HashMap<Integer,String> findup=new HashMap<Integer,String>();

    String[] Alltokens={"This","is","a","programming","test","This","is","a","any","language"};
    for(String s:Alltokens)
        lookup.add(s);

    String[] tokens={"This","is","a"};
    Collection<String> tok=Arrays.asList(tokens);

    lookup.remove(Alltokens[5]); 
     if(lookup.containsAll(tok))
       System.out.print("found");
    else    
        System.out.print("NOT found");

    Integer i=0;
    for(String s:Alltokens)
        findup.put(i++,s);
    boolean found=true;
    findup.remove(Alltokens[0]);
        findup.remove(5);               //Edit : trying to remove value whose key is 5
    for(String s:tokens)
        if(!findup.containsValue(s))
            found=false;
    System.out.print("\nIn map " + found);
}
```

Output
NOT found
In map true

Is there a way to keep containsAll consistent if remove method is called on the HashSet?
Also if a value that was not present in the set is passed to remove method.ContainsAll remains consistent

```
        lookup.remove("Alltokens[5]");
    if(lookup.containsAll(tok))
```

//This will be true now where as it is false if a value already present is removed

May be it has got to do something with keys in HashMaps and no keys in HashSet.Can you please explain how do they work?

Comment: There's something missing after `lookup.remove(Alltokens[5]);`.

Comment: The above code will not compile. You should post the actual code, and you should add `{ }` rather than allowing one-line statements to cause these issues for you, as you refactor your code and they change from one-liners to multi-liners.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Sorry the if condition went missing.edited it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Map.remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) removes a mapping *based on the **key***.

Since you use `Integer` objects as the keys (`put(i++, s)`) you will remove *nothing* when you call `findup.remove(Alltokens[0])`! Check its return value to see that it will return `false`.

Comment: I changed it to findup.remove(5) even then it returns true.Moreover how would this figured out if i have passed a key or a value.If the method takes a key as an argument won't it have tried to convert a string to an integer in the case findup.remove(Alltokens[0])

Comment: 1.) 5="This" and "This" is contained twice in your map: once at 0, once at 5. So even after you removed 5, "This" is still contained in the values of the map and 2.) No, a `String` is simply never `equal` to an `Integer`, so it will just never remove anything. Java doesn't do automagic type conversion for you, most of the time.

Comment: And in case of a HashSet after Alltokens[5] is removed since it doesn't contain duplicates 'This' is no more there and it returns false.But why doesn't  findup.remove(Alltokens[0]) give an error.Isn't it an error to pass a string to a function which takes an integer?

Comment: The reason that compiles is that `remove()` accepts an `Object`, no matter what the key type is. The [reason is complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic) and *most of the time* it's an error to pass in something that's not of the type of your key, but unfortunately that decision is fixed and can't easily be changed.