# Force properties (as in interfaces) on type parameters for Map implementations

Tags: java, generics, collections, overriding, type-erasure

I want to implement the  Map interface, but bound   K and V to interfaces). However given that the Java collections API, and specifically the MAP interface restricts the method parameters at a minimum, using Object instead of the generic types K and V. To exemplify the interface specifies: `public boolean containsValue(Object value)` instead of `public boolean containsValue(V value)`. I can not rely on compiler type safety in such occasions.

To be clear, i want to implement something like the following:

`class MyMap< K , V extends ValueInterface> implements Map<K,V>`

However, I am required to implement methods like the following:

```
@Override
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
      // What to do here? 
      ValueInterface v = (ValueInterface ) v; 
      v.getWhatIWant().andDoThing(); 
      // Follow on... 
}
```

Which options and/or best practices I have in this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by your 2nd statement?

Comment: This question has some interesting answers about why the `Map` interface does not use the generic types for some method parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic

Comment: @RohitJain I edited the question. Hope its better know. But the code exemplifies that I have to deal with an Object due to the interface contract but I wanted V to be sure that I had the possibility to rely on the ValueInterface properties.

Comment: @andersschuller Yes it is an interesting question and answers. I am really curious about it, but it seems to be no consensus in the reasons behind that decision. Additionally, i would like to see an evaluation to that design in the context of my problem.

Comment: http://smallwig.blogspot.in/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the interface contract of `Map` - as such you must implement the contract as it stands.

However, let me suggest two reasons why the design of this part of the `Map` is a good thing:

i) The `Map` [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) is that you can get values from the map under the following circumstances:

> if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that
>   (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)), then this method returns v;
>   otherwise it returns null. (There can be at most one such mapping.)

or equivalently, and specific to your question about `containsKey(Object key)`:

> Returns true if this map contains a mapping for the specified key. More formally, returns true if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key k such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)). (There can be at most one such mapping.)

As such, you are not concerned about *typing*, but about *equality*.

ii) This is really just the same point, but consider the following:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
String key = "A Key";
Integer value = 1;
map.put(key, value);

Object objectKey = key; // this is the same key object, but it is typed as Object
map.containsKey(objectKey); // what would you want/expect this to return?
map.get(objectKey); // ...or this?
```

As such, with regard to your implementation of `Map`, I would not advise just casting the `Object` key (you'll get a runtime exception...). How you decide to implement it will depend on your design. Let us imagine that you're storing the keys and values in typed lists... then you would be advised to check the `instanceof` the `Object` key before casting:

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
  if (key instanceof K) {
    // do your thing...
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Note that `instanceof` checks the type of the underlying object, not its declared type, so:

```
String key = "A Key";
Object objectKey = key;
boolean isString = (objectKey instanceof String); // is true
```

Really, I would suggest that rather than asking how to force something that goes against the `Map` contract, you want to be asking the question ["why is the contract that way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)"...

Comment: I have the feeling that the contract is that way because of the equality based implementations. This sounds bad to me since it looks like they have let implementation details escape into the design of the interface. However, in the specific context of this question I really do not care about the reasons behind that decision. I just want to known if I should: avoid implementing Map or work around this problem with casting (with the careful use of instanceof off course) or someother generic magic I do not known about.

Comment: @fabiim - this design in the Map interface is _a good thing_ (and you should care about it, because understanding why it is a good thing will better enable you to use generics in Java). There is nothing magic about Java generics - they are an extremely useful part of the language, albeit one that requires some time and care to learn/understand. As regards your particular usage, it all depends on what you are trying to achieve... at the moment your original question says "I want to implement the Map interface...", for which (unsurprisingly) you will need to implement the Map interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *implement* `Map<K,V>` you will be required to implement all methods in the interface.

You could *extend* `AbstractMap<K,V>` and override the abstract methods, plus any non-abstract methods for which you want custom behavior (as long as you don't violate the `Map` contract).

Comment: So in essence, your answer is: Well, you can't do nothing except to cast and hope for the better (if you want to implement Map<K,V>) :)

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.  The `Map` interface was originally designed before generics, and I guess that changing the signature would break too much existing code.