# ArrayList to HashMap function behaving oddly

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So I am working on the question of the best way of finding the two most common elements in an array list.

My method is to turn the whole thing to a hashmap, then see which one is the greatest. Because I like hashmaps. They seemed like a good way to do it and I wasn't able to come up with a better solution.

Except that I am getting an error. Which is where you come in (= !

```
public static String[] findTwo(ArrayList<String> param) {   
    Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < param.size(); i++) {
        //param.get(i) is name of inserted object
        if (counter.get(i) == null) {
            counter.put(param.get(i), 1);
            System.out.println(counter.get(i) + "<-- should be 1"); // <-- erroneous part!
        } else {
            counter.put(param.get(i), counter.get(i)+1);
            System.out.println("elsing");
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This code prints

```
null<-- should be 1
{HIHI=1}
null<-- should be 1
{HIHI=1}
null<-- should be 1
{HIHI=1}
null<-- should be 1
{HIHI=1}
null<-- should be 1
{yoyo=1, HIHI=1}
null<-- should be 1
{yoyo=1, HIHI=1}
null<-- should be 1
{yoyo=1, nono=1, HIHI=1}
null<-- should be 1
{yoyo=1, nono=1, froyo=1, HIHI=1}
```

Which is completely wrong!

It is saying that the value is null after I insert a 1. I am not sure why that is? =(

Ahhh thank you all!

Can anyone help me figure out what the time cost is?

Comment: Dude. Not `counter.get(i)`. `counter.get(param.get(i))`. at the top of your loop, do something like `String nextString = param.get(i)`, and you won't get confused later on

Comment: What IDE or compiler are you using?  `counter.get(i)` should raise an error or warning, since i is not a String.  And that error would help lead you to the fix.

Comment: eclipse!!! aaahhh lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`counter.get(i) == null` should be `counter.get(param.get(i))`

The fact `counter(i)` compiles is because [`Map#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) receives an `Object` and `i` gets autoboxed from `int` to `Integer` (which is an `Object`).

A better approach would be using enhanced `for` loop iteration over your `List<String> param`:

```
for(String parameter : param) {
    if (!counter.containsKey(parameter)) {
        //logic key is not present...
    } else {
        //logic when key is present...
    }
}
```

Also, start programming oriented to interfaces instead of class implementations directly. Use `List` backed by `ArrayList`:

```
public static String[] findTwo(List<String> param) {
    //...
}
```

More info on this:

- [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Comment: How does `counter.get(i)` even compile, since counter is defined as a `Map<String, Integer>`?  Should have been a compiler error or warning.

Comment: @user949300 because [`Map#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) receives an `Object` and `i` gets autoboxed from `int` to `Integer` (which is an `Object`).

Comment: Hmm, seems like `Map.put()` checks the params vs. the generics, but not `Map.get()`.  Interesting obscure knowledge.  Anybody know why? And yet another example of autoboxing strangeness.

Comment: @user949300 I won't say its obscure since it is documented and published online.

Comment: At the very least, it fails the principle of least astonishment.  I just read the comments and links from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic and it's pretty obscure!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem.

Change your following line of code

```
System.out.println(counter.get(i) + "<-- should be 1");
```

To

```
System.out.println(counter.get(param.get(i)) + "<-- should be 1");
```

Reason is, you are making `param.get(i)` as key to your counter map `counter.put(param.get(i), 1);` and getting it using `i`. So it is returning `NULL` which is true as there is no value mapped at key `i`.