# Can’t get value of Map<Long, String> by key

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, hashmap, el

I have a `<p:dataTable>` where each row has an inputText like this:

```html
<p:dataTable ... rowIndexVar="row">
    <p:column>
        <p:inputText value="#{myBean.items[row + 1]}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The `items` property is a `Map<Long, String>`:

```
private Map<Long, String> items = new HashMap<Long, String>();
```

When I submit some data and manually iterate over the map, it apparently works:

```
Iterator itr = items.entrySet().iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) itr.next();
    System.out.println("key: " + e.getKey() + " " + "value: " + e.getValue());
}
```

I get:

```
key: 1 value: item1
key: 2 value: item2
key: 3 value: item3
key: 4 value: item4
```

However, when I try to get a specific item by key

```
String item = items.get(1);
```

then I get a `null`. Based on the map's contents I should get `item1`. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: why not just use the p:dataTable var ?

Comment: I'm also using p:dataTable var... this var have strings and I can't use it in my Map. I only need to know how can I put the content of the var row inside #value="" or why items.get(1) doesn't work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `1` which you specified in `items.get(1)` is specified as an `int` and autoboxed to `Integer`. This doesn't `equals()` a `Long` value of `1` and hence the key is never found.

```
Integer int1 = new Integer(1);
Long long1 = new Long(1L);
System.out.println(int1.equals(long1)); // false
```

You need to specify the `1` as `Long` instead of (implicitly) as `Integer`.

```
String item = items.get(1L);
```

In case you wonders why you didn't got a compilation error here, it's because [`Map#get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) takes an `Object` instead of `K` for the reasons mentioned here: [What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic).

Comment: Oh! ok. My first option was Map<Integer,String> and I continued using an int. Now it works when I specify the 1 as Long. Thanks a lot for your answer.