# Java Generic type get call with invalid class causes no compiler error

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

Why doesn't this Java code generate any compiler error?

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
m.get(1);
```

I try to find an Integer in a map which maps Strings to Strings. This is clearly a programming mistake.

Similarly, this code does not generate an error either:

```
Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
m.get("dd1");
```

So Java compiler does not seem to check the type of the argument to Map.get(Object) method. Any ideas?

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic

Comment: "This is clearly a programming mistake." No it is not. Objects of one class can be equal to objects of another class. It happens to not be the case for `Integer` and `String`, but it can happen in general.

Answer (score 4):

> Java compiler does not seem to check the type of the argument to Map.get(Object) method.

Certainly it does. It checks that it's an `Object.` There's nothing else for it to check. The only way there can be an 'invalid class' is if you are using a primitive type.

Answer (score 3):

`Map`  interface `get` method takes `Object` as a argument.

No error in both the cases. The only thing is it must be an Object and if the equals method satisfied with passed Object, then the value returns.

Comment: It doesn't have anything whatsoever to do with Generics. The same applied in 1998. The argument is an `Object,` it is checked to be an `Object.`

Comment: @EJP What I mean is For example if  OP using `get(T)` , then he might realizes that it's a benefit of making it as a Object. What you told is mentioned in my first point.

Comment: There is no such thing as `get(T).` The method is defined as `get(Object).`

Comment: @EJP Where T is object and my sentence might misleading. Just edited.

Comment: You're beating about the bush. It didn't just 'mislead', it was *wrong.* There is no `T,` and there are no Generics.

Comment: @EJP Got it, What you just said. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

`m.get(Object);` argument here is valid for any object type in your map. So that will not give you compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it check at the time of insertion. in `put` method.

when no wrong data inserted in `map` then not required to check while getting data using `get` method

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation of ([Java-Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)) the get method does not use the generic injection, but instead Object as input parameter. So you will get a ClassCastException at Runtime. This differs from the put method where the generic type injection is used.

Comment: "So you will get a ClassCastException at Runtime." No you won't. It can't. Read the contract of the `get` method.

Answer (score -1):

it will check your put action and the return value（ public V get(Object key)   ）, not all of the action.

Comment: question has nothing to do with `put`