# Map contract: put() and remove() arguments

Tags: java, dictionary, interface

I just noticed a strange thing that I never paid attention to. `java.util.Map` is generic, parameterized with `K, V`. For some reason, part of the methods take `Object` as an argument, when I would expect it to be either `K` or `V`.

For example, put method is defined as expected: `V put(K key, V value)`. But get and remove methods are not: `V get(Object key)` and `V remove(Object key)`. Both of them have a note that `ClassCastException` will be thrown when key cannot be cast to `K`.

The same goes for `Multimap` in guava library, where I actually noticed this.

Can someone please explain me the reasons these methods take `Object` instead of `K` or `V`?

Comment: I always thought they were'nt generics because they only use `equals` on the parameter. Are you sure they throw a `ClassCastException` ?

Comment: @zakinster I haven't tested it yet, but javadoc for `remove()` says: `ClassCastException if the key is of an inappropriate type for this map`.

Comment: The answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic) suggests that you may be able to use `get` with an instance of a class other than `K`. I guess it depends on the implementation.