# Strange behavior when using Enum as type in Map

Tags: java, generics

When I am using an Enum as a type in Map, I am not getting a compile time error if I use a key whose type is different. For example in the code snippet below, I expected a compile time error when I tried accessing the map with a key whose type is String.

Why does generic not provide compile time safety when using generics in Map? 
When I try to insert an entry compile time check works.

With List this does not seem to be the case as I get a compile time error.

Consider the code sample below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class TestEnumGeneric{

    enum Sample{
            A,B
        }
    enum Sample2 {
          C,D
        }
    Map<Sample,String> someMap = new HashMap<Sample, String>();
    Map<String,String> someOtherMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<Sample> someList = new ArrayList<Sample>();

    public void testMapWithEnum() {
        String value = someMap.get("123");
        value = someMap.get(Sample2.C);
        String value2 = someOtherMap.get(1);
        //someMap.put("123","123");
        //someList.add("123");
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic

Answer (score 2):

The signature of `Map.get` is

```
V get(Object key);
```

So it accepts any `Object` but only returns `V`. There is nothing wrong at compile time with your usage of `get`.

NetBeans warns about this usage:

> Suspicious call to java.util.Map.get: Given object cannot contain instances of String (expected Sample)

The signature of `Map.put` is

```
V put(K key, V value);
```

So you *must* use proper types.

**Edit:**

To quote the JavaDoc:

> If this map contains a mapping from a key `k` to a value `v` such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`, then this method returns `v`; otherwise it returns `null`.

It only matters that `key.equals(k)`, they don't have to be of the same type.

Comment: If you use Eclipse, FindBugs also gives a warning for this as well.