# How to get the key of a TreeMap by it's index?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to get the key of a TreeMap by an int index.

Here's my code:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
map.put("hi", 1);
map.put("hi2", 5);

System.out.println("Key: " + (String) map.keySet().toArray()[0] + "\nValue: " + map.get(0));
```

But when I execute this, I get the error:

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

So I'm trying to get the key: "hi2"

Comment: Wait.  *What* is it you're trying to do again?

Comment: You must at least show us how your map is declared and instantiated. We don't anything about the type of your variables. Plus, your question seems weird to me.

Comment: If you need to get the element by its index (rather than its key), you need to consider the question whether `TreeMap` is the right data structure for your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to display the key located at the i index

Comment: Well if your key has type String you cannot do map.get(0). And of course, since the value is of type int you cannot cast it to String. You are interverting the types of your map.

Comment: A TreeMap uses a tree as its internal structure. Trees don't have indices. Arrays and lists have indices.

Comment: So wait.  If I understand you correctly, you want to extract the *key* of the map given a specific *value*, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is

```
"\nValue: " + map.get(0)
```

The argument for `get` must be a `String`, not an `Integer` like `0`. So do this:

```
String key = map.keySet().toArray()[0];
Integer value = map.get(key);
System.out.println("Key: " + key + "\nValue: " + value);
```

Comment: Thanks I got it! When I wrote this, I thought the get method got the value by it's index, but thanks works now!

Comment: It's obviously that. However, it makes me wonder why the get method takes an Object parameter and not a String.

Comment: What `Object` parameter?

Comment: The Map interface is declared as `Map<K,V>` so I wonder why get is declared as `V get(Object)` and not `V get(K)`. But I guess a comment is not the right place for that.

Comment: @Dici: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the error comes from the latter part of the `println` statement:

```
println(...map.get(0))
```

Where the integer `0` has a type conflict with the map, where the key type is `String`.

[edit]

- As for the original question about getting the key by index, I think you did it correctly: `map.keySet().toArray()[0]`
- For the error complaining about key type conflict in `map.get()`, you can correct the parameter type, as suggested by @Tichodroma's answer above.

Comment: Thanks @Tichodroma for the suggestion to improve the answer!  I added two actionable suggestions.