# Why does Google Guava's Multimap.get(TKey) method not instead accept Object?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, collections, multimap

There must be a good reason, or some history behind this design decision.  Or perhaps I misunderstand the use case.

Background: Google Guava has a `Multimap` interface.  The `get` method has signature: `Collection<V> get(@Nullable K key)`.  I expected: `Collection<V> get(@Nullable Object key)`

Normally generic map-like interfaces accept `Object` to `get` methods as it helps with wildcards.  See Java's `Map` interface (and [What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)).

I have a method that accepts a Multimap with wildcards, such as: `void doWork(Multimap<? extends MyKeyType, ? extends MyValueType>)`.  However, even with a `MyKeyType` reference, I cannot call (effectively) `Multimap.get(? extends MyKeyType)`.  (The code will not compile.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, just because this eliminates a lot of dumb errors when you supply something wrong to `get()` method and just have `null` returned without any compilation error or runtime exception. Such problems in the code can only be discovered using static analysis tools like FindBugs (see [GC_UNRELATED_TYPES](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#GC_UNRELATED_TYPES) pattern), but even FindBugs cannot detect every possible such bug.

As for your case: probably you have to introduce the generic parameter instead using

```
void <T extends MyKeyType> doWork(Multimap<T, ? extends MyValueType> mmap) {}
```

And every instance of your key reference should actually have the `T` type. If it's impossible for you, then you may use ugly unchecked cast like this:

```
((Multimap<MyKeyType, ? extends MyValueType>)mmap).get(key)
```

Probably it's a good idea to assign casted multimap to the intermediate variable.

Comment: As an alternative, you can use `asMap` to get a `Map` view of the `Multimap`.

Comment: Ironically, Kevin Bourrillion (Guava co-lead) wrote about this matter here: http://smallwig.blogspot.com/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html, and said: _So what to do about this vexing source of bugs, as illustrated at top? Well, when I typed that code into IntelliJ, it flagged a warning for me right away. This let me know to either fix the problem or add an annotation/comment to suppress it. Problem solved._

Comment: @kevinarpe, Link you have posted is little distorted.
Here is the updated link: http://smallwig.blogspot.in/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html

Comment: BTW he is not the author of MultiMap interface.
@Tagir, As kevinarpe rightly mentioned that dumb bugs can be caught using good Editors but logically API has to be correct.