# Getting null value in HashMap object while invoking hashmap.get(object)

Tags: java, null, hashmap

I have implemented HashMap for storing hotel booking entry.But I'm getting null values on .get(object) method even it contains all keys and returning keys correctly.I already override equals() & hashCode() methods in two different class (bookingSeason & entry) because bookingSeason class is used in some other class also and it works correctly but in entry class it does not work.

```
public class Entry {
String code;
List<BookingSeason> booking=new ArrayList<>();  

public Entry(String code) {
    this.code=code;
}

 @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if(o==null)
        return false;
    if(!(o instanceof Entry))
        return false;
    Entry room=(Entry) o;
    return this.code.equals(room.code)&&
            this.booking.equals(room.booking);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
   return Objects.hash(code,booking);
}
}
public class BookingSeason {
LocalDate startDate;
LocalDate endDate;
public BookingSeason(LocalDate startDate,LocalDate endDate) {
    this.startDate=startDate;
    this.endDate=endDate;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object)
{
    if(object==this)
        return true;
    if(!(object instanceof BookingSeason))
        return false;
    BookingSeason bS=(BookingSeason) object;
    return Objects.equals(startDate,bS.startDate)&& Objects.equals(
            endDate,bS.endDate);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(startDate,endDate);
}
}
public class Hotel {
List<BookingSeason> bookPeriod=new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<Long,Entry> roomEntry =new HashMap<>();
long num;
Entry newRoom=new Entry();
for(int i=101;i<=199;i++) {
        num=i;
        newRoom.code="A";
        newRoom.code=newRoom.code.concat(String.valueOf(i));
        roomEntry.put(num,new Entry(newRoom.code));
        System.out.println(roomEntry.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the code which you found to return a(n unexpected-by-you) `null` value?

Comment: in a for() loop

Comment: Well, show it. As it is, your question fails the completeness part of a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
roomEntry.put(num,new Entry(newRoom.code));
```

uses the long value `num` to enter the new `Entry` object into the hashmap.

```
System.out.println(roomEntry.get(i));
```

uses the int value `i` to try to get the `Entry` object.

But, since

```
Long.valueOf(11).equals(Integer.valueOf(11)) == false
```

it will not found the entry. You need to pass a long/Long value to the get method. Therefore, either using

```
 System.out.println(roomEntry.get(num));
```

or using

```
System.out.println(roomEntry.get((long) i));
```

will solve your problem.

For reference see also [What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Simply change the for loop from this:

```
for(int i=101;i<=199;i++) {
```

to this:

```
for(long i=101;i<=199;i++) {
```

Explanation:

What you have done wrong here is that you are trying to pass an `int` into the `get` method of `HashMap<Long, Entry>`.

Since the `HashMap` uses `long`s as keys, whenever the `get` method sees you try to use some other type of incompatible value, like `int`, it just returns null!

Although the integer `i` you passed into `get` has the same hash code as the long `num`, the `get` method treats them as "not the same".

Why?

Think about what would happen if `get` allowed you to use an object that is of unrelated type to the key type of the hash map to access a value:

```
class A {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return 1; }
}

class B {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return 1; }
}

// in some method
HashMap<A, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(new A(), "some stuff");
map.get(new B()); // returns "someStuff"! makes no sense, right?
```