# Collections - Long class hashcode vs Integer class hashcode

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashcode

I have below code to check if sum of distinct pairs is equal to a number.

```
static int numberOfPairs(int[] a, long k) {
                Integer
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int count =0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++) {
                if(a[i]+a[j] == k){
                    if((!map.containsKey(a[i])) && (!map.containsKey(k-a[i]))) {
                        map.put(a[i], a[j]);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

containskey method does not work for above code bcoz k is of type long.But code works if I convert long to int.

```
static int numberOfPairs(int[] a, long k) {
                Integer
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int count =0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++) {
                if(a[i]+a[j] == k){
                    int x=(int)k-a[i];
                    if((!map.containsKey(a[i])) && (!map.containsKey(x))) {
                        map.put(a[i], a[j]);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Que : why didn't it work with long type?how does the containsKey method work?

Answer (score 1):

> map.containsKey(k-a[i])

This is checking for the presence of a `Long` in a `Map<Integer, Integer>`. This will always be false, even if the numeric value happens to be the same.

Note that `long` needs to be boxed to be used as the argument to `containsKey(Object key)`, but it will be auto-boxed to `Long`, not `Integer`.

A static code checker like Findbugs may give you a warning about this. If generics had made their way earlier into Java, this would probably even be [the compile-time error you'd want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic) here.

> map.containsKey((int)(k-a[i]))

Now you have an `int`, which will be boxed automatically to an `Integer` and it works.

Comment: Right.But, on what basis containsKey will check if the specified key is present or not?  As per my understanding,it will calculate the hashcode of object which we pass.here I am passing key as 2 for(ex.),then every time I call containsKey(2) I should get the same hashcode right?then why doesn't it work?please clarify.

Comment: It looks at the hashcode first to find the bucket an object should be in, but it still compares the objects found in that bucket using `equals` afterwards (because a hashcode can collide). And that `equals` fails between Long and Integer.