# Why this String HashMap cannot get correct value by *char* key

Tags: java

I have this String to String map, and I am trying to pass `char` as a key

```
Map<String, String> phone = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("2", "abc");
    put("3", "def");
    put("4", "ghi");
    put("5", "jkl");
    put("6", "mno");
    put("7", "pqrs");
    put("8", "tuv");
    put("9", "wxyz");
  }};

String letterList = phone.get('2');  //null
String letterList = phone.get(String.valueOf('2'));  //it works
```

Why does the first case not work? In my understanding, `char` can be implicitly converted to String "2", and HashMap use `equals()` to compare keys, so that it should retrieve the key in map?

Comment: What makes you think characters are implicitly converted to strings?

Comment: A better question might be "Why does `HashMap.get` not throw an exception when you pass it the wrong type?" (after all, `Map.get` declared it throws ClassCastException)

Comment: Side note:  Don’t use “double brace initialization” to initialize a Map.  It creates a memory leak.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java and https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the first case not work? In my understanding, char can be implicitly converted to String "2"

Your understanding is incorrect. A `char` will **not** be implicitly converted to `String`. If you look at the documentation, you will see this method [`get(Object key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-). I don't know why this isn't `get(K key)` instead. However, this explains why your first example compiles without any errors: the `char` constant is autoboxed into a `Character` object. Since the `Character` with the value `'2'` is not a key in your `Map`, `get()` returns `null`.

Comment: I see, but it passes the compiler, so somehow it converts to some string?

Comment: @weijia_yu, the docs will explain everything: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object- (i`get`accepts `Object`)

Comment: I see, so map didn't do type match for `get`, it accepts `Objects`, not `K`

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic) is a thread about why it accepts `Object` instead of `K`. And [here's](http://smallwig.blogspot.com/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html) an article linked in Jon Skeet's post

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.Map` uses Objects only as a key so whenever you do `map.get('c')` since c is a char the compiler will do autoboxing operation parsing the char c primitive into `Character` Object (not String as you thought)

So at the end compiler will parse the following:
`map.get('2')` into > `map.get(Character.valueOf('2'))`

And since `Character.valueOf('2')` key does not exist in your map null is returned