# Methods of list (like remove, contains, removeAll) have Object type arguments instead of generic <T> type

Tags: java, collections

```java
public boolean remove(Object o) { 
// implementation
}
```

This is an `ArrayList` method which takes object type as argument.
Lists are always generic in Java, then why does the method accept Object type as argument instead of `<T>`.

Comment: Because these methods existed before generics was added in java.

Comment: @LarsChristianJensen: Sure, but that's also true of many of its methods that *were* retrofitted to become generic, e.g. `add`. So a specific decision was made to let these few still take `Object`.

Comment: `Object` based parameters already work fine (there are no subclass-specific properties which remove or add needs to work with; only ones which exist already in `Object`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic

Comment: Generics exist simply to turn runtime `ClassCastException` into compile-time errors. The methods which *are* generic on collections are methods which could result in a runtime error, such as those which add to the collection, or get from the collection. Removing an object from the collection *can't* result in a ClassCastException, so it is safe for it to accept `Object`, even if the object to be removed cannot possibly exist in the collection.

Comment: @AndyTurner We were once hunting a bug for two days, wondering why some entries weren't removed from a hashmap. In the end, we figured that the hashmap contained STRING keys (representing uuid values), and we directly called map.remove(someUuidInstance) ... and of course a UUID object isnt the same as a "uuid string" ... so, at least me, I would have preferred that the compiler prevented us from doing something that *makes no sense*.

Comment: @GhostCat oh, sure, there are times when you wish it could be more helpful, but this is why I opened my comment with "Generics exist simply to turn runtime ClassCastException into compile-time errors". We mitigate this type of error using [Error Prone](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/CollectionIncompatibleType).

Comment: @AustinSchäfer except for specific collection which need the type, like `EnumSet` or `TreeMap`.

Comment: @AndyTurner “*Removing an object from the collection can't result in a ClassCastException*” [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) says otherwise, and a trivial example is `new TreeMap<>().remove(new Object());`…

Comment: @Holger I should have been more precise: it does not store an out-of-bounds instance in the collection, so you won't later get a CCE from the automatically-inserted casts when consuming the stored elements.

Comment: @AndyTurner So you meant, removal can not lead to *heap pollution*. That’s right, but doesn’t explain the reasoning behind not making this method type safe. E.g. sorting a collection can not lead to heap pollution either, still, the signature of [`Collections.sort(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) enforces comparable elements. Which is reasonable, as you said, Generics exist simply to turn runtime `ClassCastException` into compile-time errors. But why not for `remove`…

Comment: @Holger it explains why it doesn't *need* to be any more type safe. The dupe explains why it isn't any more type safe.

Comment: @AndyTurner a heap pollution might be worse than a simple `ClassCastException`, but I still agree to your original statement that Generics should prevent such `ClassCastException` at compile-time. That’s what Generics was made for and there’s no “it’s fine when there’s no heap pollution” rule. And the linked Q&A doesn’t actually explain it, besides saying that it caused problems with some existing software, not naming the affected software nor the problems. And the examples of the other answers are so horrible, that they actually suggest that it shouldn’t work that way.

Answer (score 1):

Because these methods existed before generics was added in java.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, because it doesn't explain how these methods differ from (say) `add`, which *also* existed before Java had generics.

Comment: @ruakh *"why does the method accept Object type as argument instead of <T>"* sounds pretty answered to me.

Comment: @AustinSchäfer But it isnt that easy, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic for example.

Comment: In the example OP cited, it is. For the other `List` methods, I'm not sure. Also, your example asks about `Maps`.