# A trap of remove and size of hashmap in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

As the code shows:
I don't understand why in the first map, the size is 100(after remove()), but in the second map, the size is 1 instead of 2. Is that because of the difference between data type stored in hashmap or?

```java
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Short, String> map = new HashMap<Short, String>();
        for (short i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            map.put(i, String.valueOf(i));
            map.remove(i - 1);
        }

        Map<Integer, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
        hashmap.put(3,4);
        hashmap.put(4,5);
        hashmap.remove(3);
        System.out.println(hashmap.size());
        System.out.println(map.size());

    }
}
```

Help me!

Comment: As a general suggestion I'd say that there are exceedingly few good reasons to even use `short` or `Short` in Java. Outside of `short[]` there are almost no benefits for using those type. Just use `int` / `Integer`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`i-1` is an `int` expression, even if `i` is a `short`.

That means you effectively call `map.remove(Integer.valueOf(i - 1))`.

An `Integer` object is never equal to a `Short` object, even if they have the same value, so the `remove` call will fail (i.e. not remove anything).

Instead you should write `map.remove((short) (i-1));`.

Why `map.remove()` even accepts objects that are not of the type of the key is [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic).