# Java: instanceof Generic

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

Isn't there any way to find the class-type of a generic?

```
if (T instanceof String) {
    // do something...
}
```

The above definitely does not compile.

Comment: is T defined as a generic parameter? please post the entire code that doesn't compile...

Comment: Yes, T is a generic parameter. This is the only code you need.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570073/java-instanceof-and-generics

Comment: Please also note that `T` is a type, not a variable. Only variables can be used on the left-hand side of the `instanceof` operator.

Comment: I'm so tempted to post the following as a technically correct answer:
void functionName(String T)... there, your code works :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Generics are a compile time feature. Generics add checks at compile time which may not have any meaning at runtime.  This is one example.  You can only check the type of the object referenced which could be a super type in code. If you want to pass the type T you have do this explicitly.

```
void someMethod(Class<T> tClass) {
    if(String.class.isAssignableFrom(tClass))
```

or

```
void someMethod(Class<T> tClass, T tArg) {
```

Note: the type might not be the same,

```
someMethod(Number.class, 1);
```

Comment: This is one of those answers that just nailed a bunch of things at once for me.

Comment: what is this? e.g. I have `T var` and how to use it with this method? `someMethod(T)` won't work... What I don't understand?

Comment: @user25 I am not sure what you don't understand. Can you clarify what you mean? It sounds like a different question to me.

Comment: @PeterLawrey http://stackoverflow.com/a/4704909/4548520 this works for me. This one I understood how to use: e.g I have `T var` and then I have to check type like this: `new Test<T>().something(var)`

Comment: @user25 the only thing you can get here is the var.getClass () there is no way to get T if you do that.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I got type of my `var`. It's all I wanted

Comment: @user25 ok, you can get the type of the object, but not the generic in this case.

Answer (score 5):

It won't compile because T is not a variable, but a place holder for a class that is defined at runtime. Here's a quick sample:

```
public class Test<T> {

public void something(T arg) {
    if (arg instanceof String) {
        System.out.println("Woot!");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test<String> t = new Test<String>();
    t.something("Hello");
}

}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work in java. see Jon Skeet's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java

Comment: @The Scrum Meister , it works for this specific case. I have tested it.

Comment: This will work because you are using `instanceof` to test against a known type, not a generic. What doesn't work is saying `if (foo instanceof T)` where `foo` is some variable, because the type that `T` represents is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

if you have subclass

`public class SomeClass extends SomeSubclass<String>{}`

and

```
public class SomeSubclass<T> {}
```

then there is a way to discover type of T by executing code

```
Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
if (t instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    Type[] actualTypeArguments = ((ParameterizedType)t).getActualTypeArguments()
    // in simple cases actualTypeArguments will contain Classes, since Class implements Type
}
```

if your case are a bit more complex (`? extends String`)` take a look at [org.ormunit.entity.AEntityAccessor#extractClass](http://code.google.com/p/jpa-unit/source/browse/ormunit-core/src/main/java/org/ormunit/entity/AEntityAccessor.java?r=0.9.1)

Answer (score 2):

If you have specific field you can just check it like below:

```
private <T> String someMethod(T genericElement)
{
    if (String.class.isInstance(genericElement))
    {
        return (String) genericElement;
    }
...
```