# Generics runtime check of 'instanceof'

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types

I have an object called `Node<Value>`. Objects `NodeInternal<Value>` and `NodeLeaf<Value>` inherit from `Node<Value>`.

I am trying to test what is the type of the object using `instanceof` as follows:

`if (node instanceof NodeInternal)`. I did not add `<Value>` because upon runtime, the type is dropped. Without `<Value>` on `NodeInternal` however, I get the following warning: `NodeInternal is a raw type. References to generic type NodeInternal<Value> should be parameterized`.

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an unbounded wildcard:

```
if (node instanceof NodeInternal<?>) 
  node = ((NodeInternal<Value>) node).SE();
```

Comment: That means it can take any object. Is that good implementation?

Comment: @Nayefc If worried about that then add a method on node that you can override in its subclasses and then call that instead of instanceOf

Comment: @Nayefc As you note, because of generic type erasure, that's all the type information you have. The `node` variable will have a generic type parameter; make sure that your code compiles without type-safety warnings.

Comment: Sounds good. Well regarding that, my `NodeInternal` has a method called `SE()`. So in `if (node instanceof NodeInternal<?>)`, I have `node = ((NodeInternal<?>) node).SE();`. I get the following error however, `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Node<capture#1-of ?> to Node<Value>`.

It asks me to change the Node argument that gets passed in from the function from `insert(Node<Value>)` to `insert(Node<?>)` which is a wrong suggestion (breaks the code). How would I invoke a method on node only if its available in NodeInternal when IT IS NodeInternal?  C++ is a lot easier when doing that.

Comment: @Nayefc - Please see my edit; you should cast the `node` to `NodeInternal<Value>` instead of `NodeInternal<?>`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Usetheinstanceofoperatorwithagenericclasshierarchy.htm

Use `<?>`.

You can also play games:

[Java: instanceof Generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704902/java-instanceof-generic)