# How can i do an instanceof check on a generics type list?

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

I am writing a method that can take different lists of 3 different objects that each extend the same superclass. The method signature looks like this:

```
private void writeObjectToCsv(File file, List<? extends ZohoData> rawDataView)
```

I need to know which list has been passed as a parameter so I want to use an instanceof check like so:

```
if (rawDataView instanceof List<ZohoChatData>)
```

However this gives me an error that says 'illegal generic type for instanceof'(ZohoChatData is marked red in the IDE). ZohoChatdata extends ZohoData so I don't understand why the compiler is giving me this error. Does anyone know?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to use `instanceof`  on each element of the list, not the list itself because the list may contain multiple different (child) instances of `ZohoData`.

Comment: I believe that due to type erasure, at runtime the second parameter becomes `List<ZohoData>`.  So it doesn't even make good sense to check the type of that list.  I would say that you might be using generics in the wrong way here.  The whole point of generics is to do things to your list which would be common to any implementation of `ZohoData`.

Comment: There are related questions shown in the right column. Especially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570073/java-instanceof-and-generics?rq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704902/java-instanceof-generic?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734720/java-generics-obj-instanceof-t?rq=1. Do they answer your question?

Comment: Generics are erased at runtime. You can't check for those. Your Parameters should ensure typesafety.

Comment: ah yes... type erasure.. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Beyond that: keep [mcve] in mind. Always always always put up enough code to *repro* the problem; instead of putting up just fractions of code; and *describing* other parts. And if you think your question is solved, consider deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issue in the past and found two possible ways to solve it:

1. Add the runtime class to the method signature or to the class which holds the method so you know which type you're using at runtime.
2. Check the list size and if it has one item, get that item and check it's type.

Also, you can move the type check to the part where the item is processed / used altogether. This would remove the issue too.

Regards,

Sem

Answer (score 1):

Generics is used only compile time the type will be erased after compilation and it will be no more at runtime. The instanceof is used to check the type of the object. So you cannot use instanceof in a Generic type class like List. To determine what type of object the list contains the ways explained by gem is good enough.