# java -- generic instance of (element instanceof E)

Tags: java, generics

I would like to determine if an object is an instanceof a generic type. How may I do this?

something like  `if (someVariable instanceof E){}` 
Thanks!

EDIT

I think I found an answer:  `if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {return false;}`

Comment: Something like that http://mindprod.com/jgloss/instanceof.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570073/java-instanceof-and-generics

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense to me. Would you mind showing us your code?

Comment: The question is valid, but doesn't have an answer in Java. The proposed answer is complete nonsense. What is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: Could the downvoter please comment? Erasure is a comprehensive limitation on the language. If you're looking for a workaround, ask and I'll edit my answer.