# Why "t instanceof T" is not allowed where T is a type parameter and t is a variable?

Tags: java, generics, instanceof, type-parameter

Eclipse says that the instanceof operation is not allowed with Type Parameter due to generic type eraser.

I agree that at runtime, no type information stays. But consider the following generic declaration of class :

```
class SomeClass<T>{
    T t;
    SomeClass(Object o){
        System.out.println(o instanceof T);   // Illegal
    }   
}
```

At runtime, no T would be present! But if I instantiate this class of type Integer, then the corresponding object will have a field t of type Integer.

Then, why can't I check the type of a variable with T which can be replaced by Integer at runtime. And I would be actually doing something like "o instanceof Integer".

Under which cases, allowing instanceof with a Type Parameter can cause trouble so that it is prohibited?

Comment: You've already said "At runtime, no T would be present", so it sounds like you're already aware of *type erasure*.  So I'm not sure why you're confused about this behaviour?

Comment: Just because its not allowed doesnt mean it can cause rouble. T is a generic type and can in fact be about anything, using it instanceof just doent make any sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Instanceof and Generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570073/java-instanceof-and-generics)

Answer (score 6):

> But if I instantiate this class of type Integer, then the
>   corresponding object will have a field t of type Integer

No, it won't. It will have a field of type Object. Just everytime you access it, it will be cast to an Integer.

Consider the following code:

```
SomeClass<Integer> c = new SomeClass<Integer>();
SomeClass untyped = (SomeClass)c; // Which type was it?
SomeClass<String> stringTyped = (SomeClass<String>)untyped; // Now it's STRING??
```

Works. Gives you a bunch of compiler warnings, but works. Because the field T is actually of type Object and can be cast to anything.

Answer (score 5):

If you need T at runtime, you need to provide it at runtime. This is often done by passing the Class<T> which T has to be.

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    final T t;

    public SomeClass(Class<T> tClass, T t) {
        if(!tClass.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be a " + tClass);
        this.t = t;
    }

    private SomeClass(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public static <T> SomeClass<T> of(Class<T> tClass, T t) {
        if(!tClass.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be a " + tClass);
        return new SomeClass(t);
    }
} 

// doesn't compile
SomeClass<Integer> intSomeClass = SomeClass.of(Integer.class, "one");

Class clazz = Integer.class;
// compiles with a warning and throws an IAE at runtime.
SomeClass<Integer> intSomeClass = (SomeClass<Integer>) SomeClass.of(clazz, "one");

// compiles and runs ok.
SomeClass<Integer> intSomeClass = SomeClass.of(Integer.class, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

After compiling statement `o instanceof T` would be `o instanceof Object` and because all types derives from Object, it will always evaluate to true. Allowing this kind of tests would give false positive results

Answer (score 3):

Because of [type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic3), this never works. At runtime, you only know that your class has a type parameter `T`, but not which type it is for a given instance. So you can't determine whether an object is of type `T` to begin with, because you don't know what `T` is, not because it would cause some sort of trouble.

If you need to do this sort of runtime check, pass a type token to your object explicitly:

```
SomeClass(Object o, Class<T> type) {
    System.out.println(type.isInstance(o));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But if I instantiate this class of type Integer, then the corresponding object will have a field t of type Integer.

Actually, it wouldn't. It'd have a field `t` of type `Object`. As you've said, generics are almost entirely syntactic sugar (the exception is that when you extend a generic class and specify a type parameter, the type remains as metadata in the class file).

Answer (score 0):

The generic type arguments are not known at runtime, so there is no class you can compare with. T is only known at compile time. Generics do only help the developer to write code easier. But at runtime, the arguments are just `Object` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Java realize its Generics using "Erasure", it can check the type and delete the type parameter information in "**COMPILE TIME**", in "**RUN TIME**" there will only the **BOUNDARIES** of the type parameters, so there will not be any thing like "Integer"