# Casting objects when returning a generics list

Tags: java, generics

I'm relatively new to Java and generics. I'm trying to understand if I'm doing something wrong or not in writing a generic method. I have the following code (greatly simplified):

```
public class ContentIniter {       
    public ContentType getContentType();
}

public interface Content {
}

public class Show implements Content {       
}

public class Movie implements Content {       
}

public enum ContentType {
    Movie, Show
}

public class Channel {

    public List<Show> getShows() {
        return getContentByType(ContentType.Show)
    }

    public List<Movie> getMovies() {
        return getContentByType(ContentType.Movie)
    }

    private <T> List<T> getContentByType(ContentType contentType) {
        List<T> typeContents = Lists.newArrayList();
        List<ContentIniter> allContentIniters = someMethod(); // Returns initers for both shows and movies
        for (Content contentIniter : allContentIniters) {
            if (contentIniter.getContentType().equals(contentType)) {
                switch (contentType) {
                case Movie:
                    typeContents.add((T) new Movie(contentIniter));
                    break;
                case Show:
                    typeContents.add((T) new Show(contentIniter));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return typeContents;
    }

}
```

My question relates to the line:

```
typeContents.add((T) new Movie(contentIniter));
```

The only way I've been able to get the code to compile is if I cast the content object to T. But that seems yucky to me (and I don't understand why the compiler can't infer the type based on the calls). Moreover, even though the code works, IntelliJ complains of an unchecked cast.

Is there a better way to write the generic method?

**UPDATE**: Screwed up the code a bit when I tried to simplify it. Fixed the reference to `typeContents`. Also, I added a bit more complexity so that it better reflects the reality, in hopes of explaining why I wasn't simply checking for `instanceof`.

**UPDATE 2**: Realized there was yet another error...`ContentIniter` doesn't implement Content. It's also worth noting, `ContentIniter` is just a made up object. If it seems weird, think of it as an Event or other Strategy that Content objects use to delegate certain behaviors.

Comment: Do you mean `typeContents.add((T) content);`?

Comment: can you show code where you are initializing 'contents'.

Comment: I did mean typeContents. I updated the code. I also added additional complexity in hopes of showing what I'm really trying to do. I think the original version oversimplified the problem.

Comment: Why is `ContentIniter` implementing `Content`?

Comment: @onepotato You're right, `ContentIniter` shouldn't be implementing `Content`. Copy and paste error.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using generics properly, you're mixing them with your enumeration when it's really not necessary. Ideally you would be calling `getContentByType<Show>()` and then determine the list of the correct type from `allContents` using reflection.

Try something more along the lines of like (untested):

```
private <T> List<T> getContents() {
    List<T> typeContents = Lists.newArrayList();
    List<Content> allContents = someMethod(); // Returns both shows and movies
    for (Content content : allContents) {
        if (content instanceof T) {
            typeContents.add((T) content);
        }
    }
    return typeContents;
}
```

And call:

```
List<Show> shows = getContents<Show>();
```

You can then restrict the types that are called on it to only those that extend `Content`.

```
private <T extends Content> List<T> getContents() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated the example so hopefully it explains why I can't use instanceof. (And thanks for the catch on T extends Content).

Comment: I believe in Java, you cannot do `content instanceof T` right?

Comment: True, some discussion on the topic here http://stackoverflow.com/q/8741984/1156119

Comment: Bah! Realized I royally screwed up the example. `ContentIniter` isn't an implementation of `Content`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is simpler than you think : you just have to check whether your instance of Content is a Show or a Movie to make your compiler happy :

```
if (content instanceof Movie)
    contents.add((Movie) content);
if (content instanceof Show)
    contents.add((Show) content);
```

Anyway, I would say that the way that you wrote your generic method is correct. But since there is a native way to check for the type of an instance (`instanceof`), you should use it :)

EDIT : I still think you should use `instanceof`.

Plus, you should use a `List<Content>` instead of a `List<ContentIniter>`, because Content is a more global type : if someone comes up with another implementation of Content, he won't have to change your code. Actually, you're doing the same thing when you use the Interface List instead of an ArrayList for example, because List is less specific than ArrayList.

Also, using an enum is not a mistake : if you want to use one, you can. But it shouldn't be used to determine the type of an instance. The type of an instance is contained in the instance itself, period. Still, I'll say that Daniel Imms' solution is more elegant than mine, and takes better advantage of Java type features.

```
public interface Content {
    public STContentType getContentType();
}

public class ContentIniter implements Content {       
}

// You can keep the enum, as long as it's not used 
// to check for the type of an instance of ContentIniter
public enum ContentType {
    Movie, Show
}

public class Show implements Content {       
}

public class Movie implements Content {       
}


public class Channel {

    public List<Show> getShows() {
        return getContentByType(ContentType.Show)
    }

    public List<Movie> getMovies() {
        return getContentByType(ContentType.Movie)
    }

    private <T> List<T> getContentByType(ContentType contentType) {
        List<T> typeContents = Lists.newArrayList();
        // Using more generic type Content
        List<Content> allContentIniters = someMethod(); // Returns initers for both shows and movies
        for (Content contentIniter : allContentIniters) {
            // If it's a Show and I asked for Shows
            if (contentIniter instanceof Show && contentType == ContentType.Show)) {
                typeContents.add(contentIniter);
            }
            // If it's a Movie and I asked for Movies
            if (contentIniter instanceof Movie && contentType == ContentType.Movie){
                typeContents.add(contentIniter);
            } 
        }
        return typeContents;
    }

}
```

Comment: Updated the example to a closer version of reality so it better explains why I didn't use instanceof.

Comment: Updated my answer too :) Be sure to read the code, and don't hesitate to ask for clarifications !

Comment: Thanks. Realized I screwed up when copying a pasting. `ContentIniter` isn't implementing `Content`.

Answer (score 0):

I removed my original answer after the code example change.

I really don't think you can avoid the cast and the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

As long as you know what you're doing, this is probably the best solution.

The alternative is to do without the `getByContentType` method and just have a bit of duplicated logic on the `getShows()` and `getMovies()` methods.

For example:

```
public List<Show> getShows() {
    List<Show> shows = new ArrayList<Show>();

    List<ContentIniter> allContentIniters = someMethod();

    for(ContentIniter initer: allContentIniters) {
        if(initer.getContentType().equals(ContentType.Show)) {
            shows.add(new Show(initer));
        }
    }

    return shows;
}

public List<Movie> getMovies() {
    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();

    List<ContentIniter> allContentIniters = someMethod();

    for(ContentIniter initer: allContentIniters) {
        if(initer.getContentType().equals(ContentType.Movie)) {
            movies.add(new Movie(initer));
        }
    }

    return movies;
}
```

Comment: Oh surely he can avoid the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") ! Java is designed to work with strongly typed objects, and it is definitely possible to take advantage of it (instead of bypassing it)...

Answer (score 0):

Use of enum seems strange here and the way you do lost advantage of using generics.

The initer things is making things even more strange and messy.

It may looks more natural with something like this:

```
public interface Content {
}

public class Show implements Content {       
}

public class Movie implements Content {       
}

//......
    private <T extends Content> List<T> getContentByType(Class<T> contentType) {
        List<T> result = Lists.newArrayList();

        List<Content> allContents = someMethod();   // ContentIniter is just a mess
                                                    // Get all content you have!
        for (Content content: contents) {
            if (contentType.isAssignableFrom(content.getClass())) {
                result.add(content);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The way to use is

```
List<Show> result = channel.getContent(Show.class);
```