# class StatusCode extends Enum<StatusCode>

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, enums

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
    implements Comparable<E>, Serializable


class StatusCode extends Enum<StatusCode>
```

In java every enum is subclass of the class `Enum`. I want to inherit `Enum` class into my custom class 'StatusCode'. I have tried to do the same, but compiler throws an error. details are as follows

```
The type StatusCode may not subclass Enum<StatusCode> explicitly
    - Bound mismatch: The type StatusCode is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends 
     Enum<E>> of the type Enum<E>
```

If I cannot extend Enum class explicitly why not? This is not a final class, what is making sure that enum class can't be extended ?

Comment: `every enum is subclass of the class Enum`. To me this sounds like you already know how to inherit from `Enum`. What is your confusion?

Comment: Enum is an abstract class and its not final. So why I am not allowed to extend the enum class?

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it clear:

> The type `StatusCode` may not subclass `Enum<StatusCode>` explicitly.

What you need to do, is just to create an `enum` type:

```
enum StatusCode { ONE, TWO; }
```

Having this `enum`, the compiler makes sure it extends `Enum<StatusCode>` and you don't have to worry about it.

You can verify this is true by running this test snippet:

```
StatusCode statusCode = StatusCode.ONE;
System.out.println(statusCode instanceof Enum);
```

Note that the `instanceof` operator doesn't need the type-parameter for `Enum`, which is a topic you can learn more about by checking out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570073/java-instanceof-and-generics).

Answer (score 0):

> Enum is an abstract class and its not final. So why I am not allowed to extend the enum class?

Enums are part of the language, so special rules apply. This is ruled out explicitly in the [Java Language Specification 8.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)

> It is a compile-time error if the ClassType names the class Enum or any invocation of Enum

It is essential for this rule to exist because otherwise you could do this:

```
public class EnumButNotAnEnum extends Enum<EnumButNotAnEnum> {

    @Override
    public EnumButNotAnEnum(String name, int ordinal) {
        super(name, ordinal);
    }

    // etc
}
```

In other words, you could create subclasses of `Enum` that could have unlimited instances.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the exact definition in Java Language specification. However what I can find is this sentence in [§8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) (Maybe it is not written directly inside):

```
The final clone method in Enum ensures that enum constants can never be
cloned, and the special treatment by the serialization mechanism ensures that
duplicate instances are never created as a result of deserialization. 
Reflective instantiation of enum types is prohibited. Together, these four 
things ensure that no instances of an enum type exist beyond those defined by 
the enum constants.
```

This statement would be violated if you could define an enum by simply extending Enum-class.
So to answer your question it is simply the compiler to prohibit extension of enum.