# Is there an elegant way to check for the object to be an instance of the generic type?

Tags: java, generics, collections

Consider the problem: someone needs to implement, say, java.util.Set< E > interface with his/her own class. The `.add(E e)` method explicitly declared to expect the object of the type denoted with the generic parameter E. However, the `.remove(Objec o)` method explicitly declare to accept **any** object.

Thinking the static typing way, one might be embarassed with such thing. He/She still needs to back up E-type objects only.

Is there an elegant way to check for the object o, given as a parameter for the remove method, to be an instance of the generic type E?

Comment: Check this solution "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570073/java-instanceof-and-generics"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic

Comment: Do you mean without repeating the name of the type parameter? Because obviously there's `if (o instanceof TheTypeParameterClass)` (not that `instanceof` is "elegant") assuming you're implementing `Set<TheTypeParameterClass>`.

Comment: An "elegant" solution has to be generic, no doubts.

Comment: To inject the name of the type with a constructor is ugly solution in the sense of cohesion as implementation do not rely on any specific type. It is also an error prone solution -- type system may became unsound by accident.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? The reasoning behind how the API works is perhaps a bit obscure and results in an API which is maybe not the most commonsensical but there's not a huge practical value in having `remove(E e)` versus `remove(Object e)` - either the element is in the collection or it's not. The only extra value you can get with checking the type would be, potentially, to throw an IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: @sisyphus
The main incosistence with having romeve(Object e) instead of remove(E e) is that concrete implementaion of Set<E>, for instance MyIntegerSet extends AbstractSet<E>, may significantly rely on the E, for instance Integer. The generics also may be restricted: MySet<C implements Comparable<C>> implements Set<C>. Thus, accepting Object instead of Integer may lead to unexpected or unpredictable behavior. The most safe answer is to decline, to reject any type other than E at compile time.
I'm looking for the most close solution.

Comment: @Lionishy: There is a reason why it is `remove(Object o)` and not `remove(E o)` -- the contract for the `remove` method in `Collection` defines `remove(o)` to remove any item `e` in the collection such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`. If you do not accept all objects you would be potentially breaking the contract.

Comment: @newacct
There's no way to accept remove(Object) and add(E) at the same time. It's just breaking the substitution principle. We all know than Java Collection is type unsound and unsafe.
Moreover if we would be interested to accept any object supporting equals method with E, we had been invent Equals<E> interface for the reomove method parameter constrains.

Comment: @newacct
In fact, the goal is not to discuss the Java Collection drawbacks, but how to live with them.

Comment: >> I have never heard of these "drawbacks" <<
Just an example: if one has a `Set` of `Integer`s backed with the `HashSet`, the `remove((short)1)` just do not remove anything, but if a `Set` is backed with the `TreeSet` the `remove` methods throws an Exception. So, the soundness of your programm may be subject not of the interface, but the implementation.