# Instanceof a generic parameter

Tags: java, loops, generics, instanceof

I feel like i have to ask this here because i can not find a proper answer somewhere else.
I'm trying to get this following code snippet to work where `componentList` is a `List<Component>`. I know some workarounds like the ones mentioned in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570073/java-instanceof-and-generics). But i just wondered if theres is some kind of expression in java to check for an `instanceof` of an generic parameter without having an instance of it. I know i could also use an `class` or some kind of value as an identifier for it.

```java
public <T extends Component> T getComponent(){
        for (Component component:componentList) {
            if(component instanceof T){
                return component;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Already thank you for your answers and the spell checking^^

Comment: It cant be done, you have to include the type as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of type-erasure, `T` is unknown at runtime, so you have to pass in a parameter to tell the code at runtime what `T` is.

```
public <T extends Component> T getComponent(Class<T> type) {
    for (Component component : componentList) {
        if (type.isInstance(component)) {
            return type.cast(component);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The caller must then supply the parameter like this:

```
Subcomponent x = getComponent(Subcomponent.class);
```

Unfortunately, there is no way around that.

Comment: `(T) component` generates a compiler warning.  `type.cast(component)` should be used instead.