# How do I choose action depending on type in this case?

Tags: java, design-patterns, type-erasure

Feel free to improve the title and to add tags. I did not know the terminology to use here.

I have classes like this:

```
abstract class A {
    void foo(Object obj) {
        pre();

        if(obj instanceof Map<String, String[]>) {
            methodA();
        } else if (obj instanceof Map<String, String>) {
            methodB();
        } else if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
            ...

        post();
    }

    abstract protected void methodA();
    abstract protected void methodB();
}

class B extends A { /* Stuff */}
```

Note that I have two different maps. But let's focus on the first, `Map<String, String[]>`. The if statment did not compile, so I tried this:

```
interface MyMap extends Map<String, String[]> {}
```

and

```
if(obj instanceof MyMap) {
```

That compiled. However, this does not seem to work.

```
Map<String, String[]> map = new Hashtable<>();
B b = new B();
b.foo(map);
```

This makes the above if statement fail, so I tried this:

```
MyMap map = new Hashtable<>();
```

But then I get this:

```
incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for java.util.Hashtable<>
```

and with

```
MyMap map = new Hashtable<String, String[]>();
```

I get this:

```
incompatible types: java.util.Hashtable<java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]> cannot be converted to MyMap
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is that previously, I had a separate method for each object. But I don't like the code duplication, because the `pre()` and `post()` are the same for all of them. How should I solve this?

Comment: Type arguments are erased at runtime, so you can only check `instanceof Map`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570073/java-instanceof-and-generics) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Comment: @user Well, it seems to be possible to check against `MyMap` too. It does compile.

Comment: Yes, but your first `map` instance has nothing to do with `MyMap`. `MyMap` is a separate interface, not a typealias.

Comment: That if/else construct smells - can you make the abstract class generic?

Comment: @AndrewS No I cannot, and yes, it definitely feels like a smell. But I think my problem is quite clear. Otherwise, just ask.

Answer (score 2):

You have some misunderstandings about java.

You seem to expect that, given:

> interface MyMap extends Map<String, String[]> {}

That you've made an ontological declaration: You seem to think this means:

"I henceforth decree that all things that are a `Map<String, String[]>` are also `MyMap`s."

Or possibly you think this means:

"I have created an alias; `MyMap` is just shorthand for `Map<String, String[]>`".

Neither is true.

The correct meaning is:

I created an entirely brand new interface called `MyMap`. Any MyMap is necessarily a Map<String, String[]>, but the reverse need not be true. Right now, other than what that Map interface demands you have as methods, I make no further demands. The only objects that are `MyMap`s are any objects created by writing `new X()`, where X is a class that explicitly has `implements MyMap` on it, or is a subclass of a class that did that.

And therefore, it is **completely useless** in trying to address your problem here.

Your second misunderstanding is generics.

Generics are primarily a figment of the compiler's imagination. **They are compiler-checked comments**. Seriously. Go check:

```
Map<?, ?> = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and

```
Map<?, ?> = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

compile  both, and do a binary diff on the result. Exactly the same bytes. Thus clearly proving that the `<String, String>` part **does not survive compilation**.

This is called erasure. There where generics appears in reflectively accessible stuff, such as in the return type of a method, or the parameter of a method, or some type in an extends clause, or a field's type - it is stored in the class file, but as a comment (as in, the JVM itself doesn't even look at it and cares absolutely not one iota about it). The comment is there for `javac` to look at, and use when compiling other code that references these fields/methods/classes.

But everywhere else? javac uses it to generate warnings, errors, and silently inject a few casts, and then it **disappears**.

Thus, this:

```
x instanceof Map<String, String>
```

**is impossible**.

You just can't check that. `x` knows that it is a `Map`. It has no idea what the generics are, though.

The solution then is to take a step back.

You had some unknown problem X, and you thought: I know! I'll write a method that takes any object, and then I'll check if the passed-in object is a `Map<String, String>`, and then I'll solve my unknown problem X! Except I don't know how to check for that so I'll ask on SO.

But this is a dead end. Go back and re-ask about 'unknown problem X'. I'm positive it can be solved, and quite easily at that, but not like this.

### A wild stab at a possible solution for you

If you're looking to eliminate code duplication, and the duplicated code you're trying to deduplicate is the `pre` and `post` in:

```
public void someMethod(SomeSpecificType x) {
    pre();
    customStuffUniqueToThisType();
    post();
}

// and 20 more of these, with the same pre and post everywhere
```

Then perhaps consider lambdas. You could make this method:

```
public <T> void apply(T obj, Consumer<T> runner) {
    pre();
    runner.consume(obj);
    post();
}
```

and you can then call it:

```
Map<String, String> obj = ....;
apply(obj, o -> {
   // o is a Map<String, String>.
   // do whatever you want here.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for a very informative post, but I think I actually did explain what problem I'm trying to solve in the bottom of the question?

Comment: I'm basically trying to init instances of B with different objects, and I have some pre and post that is the same in all cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but in my case, I don't think it's worth all the hazzle. So I accept some code duplication in this case. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common use case already solved multiple times in the object oriented world.

What you are looking for is a combination of  [Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and the [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

1. After reading up on the Template pattern, it should be clear that your code is somewhat already using this pattern. (Although : `foo` should be `final`)
2. I would make class `A` take a type parameter (i.e `abstract class A<T>`). I would create a constructor in `class A` that takes T as input (i.e `A(T t) { this.t = t}`)
3. Instead of having 2 methods namely `methodA` and `methodB`, I would simply have one abstract method called `doSomething(T t)`; I would call it only once, passing it the `t` instance variable. I would remove all the if-else conditions. The final implementation of   `foo` would be `foo() { pre(); doSomething(t); post() }`
4. class `B` can then extend `A` and implement `doSomething(T t)`. Example : `class B extends A<Map<String, String[]>> { doSomething(<Map<String, String[]>> t) {...do something..} }`
5. Similarly, I can create one subclass each for handling `Map<String, String>` and `JSONObject` respecrively.
6. At this point, I have different implementations of `A`. I need to have a `Context` class that will be passed an `A` and it will call `a.foo()`. I need a `Factory` class that creates a `Context` class and passes it the right instance of a subclass `A` depending on some runtime input parameter.

Comment: Thank you. The reading gave me some insight, but I think I'll stick to some minor code duplication. Answer upvoted.

Comment: @klutt Thanks for your comment. I would highly recommend that you avoid code duplication and have conditionals in one single place in the application (Read : Factory). What may seem like a non-issue today can easily pose as a code-smell that becomes almost impossible to refactor when the code base grows larger..