# Implement remove(Object o) in generic collection

Tags: java, generics, collections, comparable

I am writing a generic collection based on a binary tree model.

```
class MyTree <T extends Comparable<T>> extends AbstractCollection<T>{...}
```

The underlying `Node<T>` class (among others) contains the following methods:

```
public Node<T> getLeft()  // left Node
public Node<T> getRight() // right Node
public T getValue()       // value stored in the Node
```

I want to override the method `boolean contains(Object o)` of the interface `AbstractCollection<T>` to have the possibility to check for `Object`'s of a type other than `T`.

For the tree traversal in O(log n) the generic type `T` must implement `Comparable<T>`, so it has the method `compareTo(T t)`.

My code:

```
@Override
public boolean contains(Object o){
    T t = (T) o; // produces warning (see below)
    BSNode<T> currentNode = this.root;
    while(currentNode != null){
        if(currentNode.getValue().equals(o)) {return true;}
        if(currentNode.getValue().compareTo(t) < 0)  {currentNode = currentNode.getRight();}
        if(currentNode.getValue().compareTo(t) > 0)  {currentNode = currentNode.getLeft();}
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that I can not just cast `Object o` to `T t` for using `compareTo(T t)`. Technically the `Object`'s are castable to `T`, but as `T` is a generic type, I get this warning:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
          T t = (T) o;
                    ^
required: T
found:    Object
where T is a type-variable:
  T extends Comparable<T> declared in class MyTree
```

Can someone either

1. confirm that I can safely ignore the warning using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`,
2. suggest how I can safely cast `Object` to `T`,
3. explain why neither of the points above can be satisfied so I can stop thinking about how to make this work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think Object can be safely cast to T since it might no be an object of type T but something else. Also, why passing an Object to your `contains()` if you are defining a collection of T type?

Comment: *Unrelated:* Instead of calling `equals` once and `compareTo` twice, just call `compareTo` once: `int cmp = currentNode.getValue().compareTo(t); if (cmp == 0) { return true; } currentNode = (cmp < 0 ? currentNode.getRight() : currentNode.getLeft());` --- Remember, `equals` and `compareTo` might be relatively expensive calls.

Comment: @Andreas I actually planned to do this once everything is working fine. Did not do it here to show the different parameter types of `equals(Object o)` and `compareTo(T)` and also to present how the method should work without adding that small layer of abstraction. Thanks anyways for the suggestion. :)

Comment: @LuisMuñoz It is generally possible that `Object o` can be cast into `T t`, as `Object.equals(Object o)` does not strictly forbid equality of `Object`'s of different types. That's why `AbstractCollection` implements `contains(Object o)`. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994123/why-do-we-have-containsobject-o-instead-of-containse-e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to have unrestricted searches, you need to do a cast. You can add `instanceof` to guard the cast from exceptions, but that is not ideal either.

Consider changing the bounds of `T` as follows:

```
class MyTree <T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends AbstractCollection<T>{...}
```

Since you do an override, suppressing the warning is pretty much required. The cast should look as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Comparable<? super T> t = (Comparable<? super T>) o;
```

See the source of `getEntry` method of `java.util.TreeMap` for an example of how it is done in [Java source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java) (they do it for the same reason - the need to override a method with a signature taking `Object`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it motivated me to take a closer look at generics in java and now everything works fine and I even understand, why. Actually `instanceof` is not just not ideal, it does not work with generics (due to type erasure). Also thanks for the referral to the source code of `java.util.TreeMap`, I did not even know a thing like the OpenJDK existed or think about the possibility to take a look at some source code.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch You can do `instanceof` with generics using the so-called "type token" trick described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html). Essentially, the caller would need to supply an instance of `Class<T>` for type `T`, giving your code access to [`isInstance(obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) method. It's unrelated to this question, just a nice thing to keep in mind when type erasure seems to get in your way with Java generics :-)