# Why does Java Map<K, V> take an untyped parameter for the get and remove methods?

Tags: java, api, generics

I ran into a bug in my code where I was using the wrong key to fetch something from a Java map that I believed was strongly typed using Java generics.  When looking at the Map Javadocs, many of the methods, including get and remove, take an Object as the parameter instead of type K (for a Map defined as Map).  Why is this?  Is there a good reason or is it an API design flaw?

Comment: Some IDEs have a warning for this situation.

Comment: While the question is not an exact duplicate, the answers can be found in the answers to another question [Why aren't Java Collections remove methods generic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic).

Comment: I think I should set up the warning in my IDE. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think this is for backwards compatibility with older versions of the Map interface. It's unfortunate that this is the case however as you're right, it would be much better if this took the correct type.

Comment: The methods can't take K as a generic type, since K does not cover all valid key types for the map (see my answer).

Comment: -1: It *would not* be better if the search key were forced to be of the same type as the map key - that's a common use-case but certainly not the only one.  I have implemented maps that have complex keys and can take simple strings or other reduced complexity keys for searching.

Comment: YUK!  I strongly disagree to this justification - i think if you want a use case where diferent types can be used as valid keys, then create overrides or extra methods that constrain the usage.  That way you have a strongly typed, clearly documented interface that indicates the intended usage.  Any generic that has an Object parameter being used is an indication of poor design IMO.  This design leaves itself to potentially dangerous situations.

Answer (score 5):

Because the map will return a value if the object passed to the get method is equal to any key stored in the map. Equal does not mean that they have to be of the same type, but that the key's and the passed object's equal methods are implemented in such a way, that the different object types are mutually recognized as equal.

The same applies of course to the remove method.

---

Example of valid code, which would break (not compile) if the get method only allowed parameters of type K:

```
LinkedList<Number> k1 = new LinkedList<Number>();
k1.add(10);

ArrayList<Integer> k2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
k2.add(10);

Map<LinkedList<Number>, String> map = new HashMap<LinkedList<Number>, String>();

map.put(k1, "foo");
System.out.println(map.get(k2));
```

Comment: While this may be correct in theory, it would be an extremely ugly hack to create multiple classes with equals() and hashcode() implementations that work this way. It seem highly unlikely to me that these methods were defined to take Objects as parameters just so people can write code like this.

Comment: @Luke Hutterman: take a look at the documentation for the equals method of the List interface. its contract says that two lists should be equal if they are both lists and their elements are the same in the same order, regardless of class of the lists. same with the Set and Map interfaces

Comment: Even if you think it's ugly, that is exactly how the Map interface and Object#equals method are defined in the API documentation. When adding generics to the Map interface, care had to be taken to not alter the defined behaviour of the interface methods. Forcing the parameter to the get method to actually be of the same type as the generic K type would be a non backward-compatible change to the interface definition.

Comment: @newacct: in that example, the values have the same type - java.util.List - even though not the same class. That would be good enough to use a more tightly constrained get. You can come up with more outlandish scenarios where valid keys share no type more specific than Object, but i can't imagine they're scenarios i would want to be possible!

Comment: @newacct: but if you declare a Map<List, SomeOtherType>, you can use any type of List. Your example (equality between different List implementations) would only be an issue if someone were to declare a Map<ArrayList, SomeOtherType> and subsequently tried to call get() using a LinkedList; again, a very ugly hack.

Comment: @Tom: No, in that example the two keys share *a common* type, being List.  The key in the map is, however, LinkedList, not List, and if the get key were typed it would prohibit use of ArrayList as a key.

Comment: @Luke: Once again; the Java API is indeed not perfect and do allow for several ugly hacks. I might not agree that this is one of them, but it should be obvious, that adding generics is not a good reason to clean up old dirt, if it breaches backward compatibility.

Comment: @jarnbjo: I don't see how your example breaks backwards compatibility - in a pre-generics world, that code would have been a plain `HashMap` where `LinkedLists` and `ArrayLists` were used interchangeably as keys. In rewriting this to generics, simply declaring the map as a 
`Map<List<Number>, String>` would have worked perfectly.

Comment: @Luke: No, it wouldn't. ArrayList<Integer> does not implement List<Number> and would not have been usable as a parameter to the get method. And if you for some other reason require the keys to be LinkedLists, you can of course not "simply declare" the Map to use List (or any other superclass of LinkedList) keys anyway.

Comment: @jambjo: You're right, `ArrayList<Integer>` does not implement `List<Number>`. However, `k2` in the pre-generics code was just an `ArrayList` that happened to contain `Integers` (just like `k1`). Your contrived example has the user adding incompatible type definitions (making one a `List<Number>` and the other a `List<Integer>`), which has nothing to do with backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Luke: Why do you respond to half of my comment and ask new questions, you would have already found answered in the second half? It is a valid use case to e.g. force LinkedLists to be used as key in the map, but still wanting to use an ArrayList as a query parameter to the get method. This is not only related to the generic type of the list. And it is of course not restricted to two different List implementations, but any other concrete classes A and B, which extend a common superclass, where the equals method is implemented in the superclass, so that A and B are equal, but of different types.

Comment: @jambjo: quite frankly, I cannot think of any valid reason why one would want to force a `LinkedList` to be used as keys in a `Map`, though I agree that the language won't stop you from doing so, nor of course should it. With it being such a strange edge-case though, I doubt this was the main reason these methods were made to take `Objects` instead of a generic type. See my answer for what I believe to be a much more likely reason these methods were made to accept Objects instead.

Comment: @Software Monkey: yes, but that's because that code is actually wrong - if it's okay to use an ArrayList as a key, then the key type is *not* LinkedList, it's List!

Comment: @Tom: What you're not getting is that a *search* key may well be legitimately broader than the *map* key.  Typing `get` and `remove` would prevent that.  The map can search using any List as key, but must store a LinkedList as key (who knows why - that is not postulated in this example).

Answer (score 3):

This was done so that if the type parameter is a wildcard, these methods can still be called.

If you have a `Map<?, ?>`, Java won't allow you to call any methods that are declared with the generic types as arguments. This prevents you from violating the type constraints so you cannot, for instance, call `put(key, value)` with the wrong types.

If `get()` were defined as `get(K key)` instead of the current `get(Object key)`, it too would have been excluded due to this same rule. This would make a wildcarded Map practically unusable.

In theory, the same applies to `remove()`, as removing an object can never violate the type constraints either.

Here is an example of code that would not have been possible if `get` had been declared as `get(T key)`:

```
public static <K,V> Map<K, V> intersect(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m1, Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m2) {
    Map<K,V> result = new HashMap<K, V>();
    for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e1 : m1.entrySet()) {
        V value = m2.get(e1.getKey()); // this would not work in case of Map.get(K key)
        if (e1.getValue().equals(value)) {
            result.put(e1.getKey(), e1.getValue());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`e1.getKey()` returns an object of some unknown subtype of `K` (the subtype used by `m1`), but `m2` uses a potentially different subtype of `K`. Had `Map.get()` been declared as `get(K key)`, this usage would not have been allowed.

Comment: You can get round this problem with wildcards by pushing the variable into a method with a type parameter of its own - eg `<T> void duplicateFirst(List<T> l) {T first = l.get(0); l.add(0, first);}`. But in this case, i struggle to see why a Map<?, ?> isn't practically useless anyway.

Comment: `Map<?,?>` may be relatively useless, but the same argument applies to, for instance, a `Map<? extends Number, String>`. The main point though is that unlike `put<K,V>`, `get()` will never violate the type constraints declared on your collection.