# Java List interface contains(Object o) method signature

Tags: java, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren’t Java Collections remove methods generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic)

The Java `Collection<E>` interface has a `contains` method with the following signature:

```
boolean contains(Object o)
```

Since the interface is generic with type `E` shouldn't the signature be
`boolean contains(E o)`

to reflect that and only allow arguments of type `E`.

The same question can be asked regarding the `remove(Object o)` method

Comment: may be it was added before generic took birth in java world

Comment: Looking at the [Collection JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)), it looks like the method is there from Java 1.2, were generics didn't exist yet in Java language.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times before: [Why does Java Map<K, V> take an untyped parameter for the get and remove methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269147/why-does-java-mapk-v-take-an-untyped-parameter-for-the-get-and-remove-methods) and [Why aren't Java Collections remove methods generic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, for the reference. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `contains` and `remove` methods accept any object because the they accept (and can succeed with) objects that might not be instances of `E`. The [contract for `contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) is:

> returns true if and only if this collection contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))

Note that `o` need not actually be an object in the collection; it must merely pass the `equals` test.

The same idea goes for `remove`.

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic?lq=1), where it is pointed out that making `contains` and `remove` generic would have broken a lot of existing, perfectly valid code.