# Remove by index in LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

This is not something which I would do in real life, but say:

`LinkedList = a,b,c,d,e` and I get their corresponding index.

Say, I want to remove `b (index=1) and d (index=3)`(i.e. values surrounding `c (index=j=2)`)

Now,I do (which works fine):

```
When j=2
LS.remove(j + 1); ----> j=3 (d removed)
LS.remove(j - 1); ----> j=1 (b removed)
```

And `b and d` are removed.

But if, I do (does not work):

```
When j=2
LS.remove(j - 1); ----> j=1 (b removed)
LS.remove(j); ----> j=2 (d is not removed) (used j because due to above removal, LL has adjusted it self)
```

i.e. when I move the value preceding 'c' first, 'd' is not removed and the LL stays as it is. I guess, I am doing the same thing.

Am I missing out on something here?

**UPDATE:**

So, when I change the signature `public void operation(String operator, Integer j) to public void operation(String operator, int j)`, it worked.

Comment: Please post a complete example, because normally this *does* work.

Comment: Correct: http://www.ideone.com/jPgt9 Wrong: http://www.ideone.com/7RPg9 PS: Not my code, I am reviewing a homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `j` is of type big `Integer`, then `LinkedList.remove(Object)` will be called instead of `LinkedList.remove(int)`. And that's not what you actually want.

I don't see any reason to use big-Integer as the type of `j` in your second example, you should use primitive `int`.

Please check [Why aren't Java Collections remove methods generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic) on why `LinkedList` still has `remove(Object)` signature.

Comment: See the wrong code here (try to debug if possible): Correct: http://ideone.com/jPgt9 Wrong: http://ideone.com/7RPg9 Line 53 is not removing the value.

Comment: @zengr It is because `LinkedList.remove(Object)` gets called. Interesting enough is that `remove` still has `public boolean remove(Object o)` singature, not `public boolean remove(E o)` thus allowing compiler to compile such code without errors..

Comment: yup, got that, updated the question. The gotcha was Integer class vs int!

Comment: more over, why does remove() has Object o? any reasoning for that?

Comment: @denis.solonenko: My +1. Somehow i missed on that. With `j` as `int` it works fine.

Comment: @zendr It is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of a hairy thing to refer to elements of a list by index when you're modifying the list -- and so the relation from index to element is changing.  This is why, in Java, [`java.util.List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) has a method [`List.listIterator()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28%29), giving a [`java.util.ListIterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).  With this, you could write a method like so:

```
void removeAdjacent(List<?> list, Object o) {
    ListIterator<?> listIt = list.listIterator();
    while (listIt.hasNext()) {
        if (listIt.next().equals(o)) {
            // set the iterator back to the element we just checked
            listIt.previous();
            // remove previous if it exists
            // and set the iterator again to this element
            if (listIt.hasPrevious()) {
                listIt.previous();
                listIt.remove();
                listIt.next();
            }
            // remove next if it exists
            if (listIt.hasNext()) {
                listIt.next();
                listIt.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, that's why I said, i would not do this in real code I am writing, but I am curious that why isn't it working?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing something. This complete program produces the expected result:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Foo {
   public static void main(String []argv) {
      LinkedList<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();
      l.add("a");
      l.add("b");
      l.add("c");
      l.add("d");
      l.add("e");
      int j = 2;
      l.remove(j - 1);
      l.remove(j);
      System.out.println(l.toString());
   }
}
```

The result is:

```
[a, c, e]
```

Comment: See the wrong code here (try to debug if possible): Correct: http://ideone.com/jPgt9 Wrong: http://ideone.com/7RPg9 Line 53 is not removing the value.