# Weird signature of Collection.remove()

Tags: java, generics, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren't Java Collections remove methods generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic)

Why is the signature of `Collection.remove()` defined as follows:

```
public boolean remove(Object o)
```

and not

```
public boolean remove(E e)
```

where E is the type of collection.

We know if `c` is a `Collection` of type `E` [`Collection<E>`] then `c` will always contain objects of `E` or sub classes of `E`. Then why don't we restrict the method parameter to either `E` or `? extends E`