# Generics inconsistently using Type?

Tags: java, generics

Here's my final class.

```
public class ActivitiesSQL implements Activities {
  ...

  @Override
  public boolean add( Activity e ) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Not supported yet." ); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
  }

  @Override
  public boolean remove( Object o ) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Not supported yet." ); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
  }
}

public interface Activities extends Repository<Activity, ActivityId> {
    ...
}

public interface Repository<T, ID> extends Set<T> {

  public abstract T findById( ID id );
}
```

What I'm trying to understand is why the generated code is `remove( Object...` and `add( Activity ...)`. Why isn't it `remove( Activity ... )`?

Comment: Because that's what your base type declares.

Comment: but `add` and `remove` AFAIK are coming from the same place, so shouldn't they both end up with either Object or Activity? in my implementing class

Comment: Where’s the remove method, you’re implementing/overriding, defined?

Comment: I guess it just never occurred to me that would be defined in Set inconsistently I thought it was something I was doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `Set` you are extending is `java.util.Set`, the argument to `remove()` is type `Object` because that's the way it's defined in `java.util.Set`.

You could define your own `remove(T)` in `Repository` and delegate to `Set#remove()` if you wanted to, but then it wouldn't be an `@Override` any more.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017730/18157) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/105812/18157)