# Java collections. add(E obj), but remove(Object obj)

Tags: java, collections, method-signature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren't Java Collections remove methods generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic)

I have a question about signature of java functions declared in **Collection**. 
The question is: why signature of `add` involves **E** (our type) but `remove` has parameter Object?

I have seen one response in WWW of this question, but I'm not sure that reason

> "in remove we only need 1 operation: equals and Object provides it"

is plausible.

Comment: There's a bunch of other places where there's a similar situation. For instance, `Map.push` takes generic parameters, but `Map.get` does not.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's left over from pre-generic days. Both the `add` and `remove` methods used to take an `Object` argument. When generics were introduced, there was good reason to change the `add` method, but there really wasn't any good reason to change the `remove` method (because the reason you cited allowed it to remain as is).

My guess is that if it were designed from scratch today, `Collection.remove` would take a generic argument, not an anonymous Object.