# Java HashMap boxed key type autocast weirdness

Tags: java, casting, key, hashmap

Just came up upon a very strange behavior of Java HashMap. The map has the `Long` type of keys, but when I access them passing an `int` key, there is no autocast, instead the `get()` method returns null as if the key does not exist! Why Java does no proper auto casting from int to long in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map.get() and remove() accept any object. Your `int` is being auto-boxed to `Integer`

It doesn't know what you meant to write is `map.get((Long) (long) intValue)` or `map.get((long) intValue)`

If you are using primitive types, rather than objects, you can try TLongObjectHashMap which does convert `int` to `long` (not the wrappers)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I cannot yet vote for you) but I will when I can.

Answer (score 1):

The [get method of the HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) accepts an Object, regardless of the generic type. The reason behind that has been explained in a different [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic/105812#105812).

In your case, the int is auto boxed to an Integer object. However, as only Long objects are stored in your map, no object for the Integer object is found. As the get method accepts any object, there is no way to know that the int should be casted to a Long. This may(!) be different if the get method would only accepts Long objects. You have to cast it yourself.