# Why lists' remove() methods take Object and not T?

Tags: java, api, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren't Java Collections remove methods generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic)

Does anyone know why `MyDamnedUnclearList.remove()` methods take `Object element` and not `T element` (or `V extends T element`) ?

I lost two hours to find a bug mixing both `int` and `Integer` Java types (in a `List<Thread>` list...

Comment: Also this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic Which I included in my answer

Comment: Hmm the question now talks about Threads... weird edit.

Comment: Thread was just my actual situation, just a example. I just wanted to show it was not generic, as you mentioned in your clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with backward compatibility of existing code and specification.

[What are the reasons why Map.get(Object key) is not (fully) generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)

Its all in the details of the Javadoc:

> boolean remove(Object o)
>
> Removes a single instance of the specified
>   element from this collection, if it is present (optional operation).
>   More formally, removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null :
>   o.equals(e)), if this collection contains one or more such elements.
>   Returns true if this collection contained the specified element (or
>   equivalently, if this collection changed as a result of the call).

So you see it doesn't matter whether the objects have the same type only that they equal.

Comment: I've read this javadoc, I just consider it was nonsense, IHMO.

Comment: Java is a very old language that has gone through many iterations and they try like hell to be backward compatible. This is akin to Python < 3.0. Java unfortunately does not have a benevolent dictator like Ruby and Python so changes that break stuff are very hard to get placed in the language (we have an evil fat/lazy dictator named oracle). If it really bothers you I recommend you look at Scala (which has the opposite problem of changing everything every release).

Comment: I often use and love coding in Scala or Haskell :)